# Why does async/await method in attribute never return

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library

Ok so bear with me this might take some explaining, i have a simple Account controller thus;

```
[RoutePrefix("api/account")]
[Authorize]
[HmacAuthentication]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await this._userService.RegisterUser(userModel);

        var errorResult = this.GetErrorResult(result);
        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }

        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

The HmacAuthentication attribute is here:

```
public class HmacAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...

        var isValid = this.IsValidRequest(req, appId, incomingBase64Signature, nonce, requestTimeStamp);

        if (isValid.Result)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    private async Task<bool> IsValidRequest(
        HttpRequestMessage req, 
        string appId, 
        string incomingBase64Signature, 
        string nonce, 
        string requestTimeStamp)
    {
        ...
        var user = await this.UserService.FindUser(userId); // this never gets a return value
        ...
    }
}
```

The method called in the `UserService` is this:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUserModel> FindUser(int id)
{
    var user = await this._userBusiness.FindAsync(id);
    return this.MapToModel(user);
}
```

and in the business class is this:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindAsync(int id)
{
    var result = await this._userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    return result;
}
```

The problem that i am facing is that when the Register method is called the HmacAuthentication attribute fires and the AuthenticateAsync filter method executes. The call in `IsValidRequest` to lookup a user is never actually getting a return value, if i try a request through postman it never completes.

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: What do you do with `isValid`?  Do you do an `await` on it anywhere?

Comment: Can you tell if the code is stuck at the line `isValid.Result`?  If so, you are probably experiencing a deadlock. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks) for why you usually do not want to use `Task.Result` to wait on a task.

Comment: sometimes var is a bad thing, it makes you forget the await...

Comment: @sstan thanks i just assumed was the above line since the debugger never got that far, the link helped as well as the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...

        var isValid = await this.IsValidRequest(req, appId, incomingBase64Signature, nonce, requestTimeStamp);

        if (isValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

As the compiler suggested, you can only use the `await` keyword inside of a method marked as `async`. So I have updated the signature for AuthenticateAsync accordingly. Also note that you can just check `isValid` now instead of doing `isValid.Result` since the value of the boolean will be available past the await line.

This can be a little confusing as the interface for IAuthenticationFilter doesn't specify async (interfaces can't, they can only indicate that the method will return a Task). It is up to the implementer to determine whether or not the method will simply return the task or will supply an async so that values can be awaited inside the method body.

Comment: I tried that but i get a compile time error `The 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier` the method i am calling from is on a framework interface `public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Comment: I didnt realize you could decorate the method with async that wasnt your method i am still trying to get my head around the await/async, but that did the trick, also thanks on the comment above from @sstan it was indeed blocked on the `isValid.Result` assumed it was the preceeding line since i never got that far when stepping through

Comment: You can only do it on interface methods that return Tasks. async/await definitely takes a little bit to wrap your head around but it is insanely powerful and once you get into it you'll find yourself wondering how you ever coded without it :)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct in how to fix your problem, but doesn't explain *why* this happens.

This:

```
var isValid = this.IsValidRequest(
                  req, 
                  appId, 
                  incomingBase64Signature, 
                  nonce, 
                  requestTimeStamp);

if (isValid.Result)
```

Is causing your code to **deadlock**. You're synchronously blocking on an async method. This happens because when the compiler sees an `async` method, it generates a state-machine which takes everything after your first `await` and wraps it as a continuation. The compiler also sees if there are any synchronization contexts involved, and if there are, it attempts to marshal the continuation back onto the `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, which is blocked by your `.Result` call, effectively causing a deadlock.

This is why [you shouldn't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)