# Why does SendMailAsync cause asp.net to wait, while Task.Delay doesn't?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I added the following line (exactly as is, so you can try it too) to an asp.net WebApi action:

```
new SmtpClient { DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory}.SendMailAsync("a@test.com", "b@test.com", "s", "b");
```

and it caused the action to wait a few seconds, until throwing a 500 error of `An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.` Clearly asp.net detected that there was an asynchronous task running.

Yet when I add

```
Task.Delay(10000);
```

the action completes immediately. Why does asp.net not detect here that there is an asynchronous task running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SmtpClient.SendAsync` has the [HostProtectionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-security-host-protection-attributes/host-protection-attributes-and-clr-integration-programming) with the `ExternalThreading` flag on. Which indicates ASP.NET that new threads will be involved, so ASP.NET starts keeping count of these operations waiting for completion.

If you need to use async methods in WebForms you should use the [RegisterAsyncTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks. Would do I do if I want to call SendMailAsync but I don't want the WebApi action to wait until the email is sent? I also don't want to tie up a thread by calling Task.Run.

Comment: You could take a look at posts like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335345/web-api-fire-and-forget Fire and forget are not a good recommendation in the Web. The WebServer could kill your process if he needs to.