# C# Fire and forget for WPF application logs, handle exit before answer

Tags: c#, fire-and-forget

I have an application that should send a log when it exits to a cloud function. This means it can take a long time to get an answer if I'm unlucky (sometimes minutes!). I don't want my application to stay in the background for that long so I just want to fire and forget the log message. I don't need 100% guarantees, but as close as possible is of course nice.

What's the best method to achieve this?
I've read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335345/web-api-fire-and-forget), but it's aimed at ASP.Net applications. Is this still applicable for a WPF application that exits and disappears, potentially before there will ever be an answer from the server, or are there better ways in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: If *anything* is quick at disapearing, it is the ASP.Net page/request. This is their lifecycle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140) | Pages are supposed to be created, process, send to the user and be dropped out of memory ASAP. And this applies to all web technology. Compared to that, a WPF application is a tectonic movement. | Multitasking usually has to be done on the client side - it is the only place where code can life long enough, to get an answer.

Comment: I follow Maxim 26. "Fire and Forget" is fine, provided you never actually forget. | Swallowing exceptions is one cardinal sin of exception handling. Normally you have to write a very bad catch for it. But Multitasking? Fire and Forget tasks? Those are *notorious* for swallowing exceptions. You would have to stop application closure, until all started tasks/threads a finished. And of obvious reasons, you should have a way to abort them. | It is not as critical on application closure - the application will end either way. But I still do not like it.