# Background Task like Fire forget in windows service application running in background

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I have a windows service running in background which do some task at every 15 minutes, but I have to call a function with multiple time like in a loop and execution for one time of that function can also take more than 15 minutes depends on configuration.
Any suggestion for that like fire and forget for achieving this.

`CallTask` is function called in Service every 15 minutes.

Sometimes `StartTask` gets executed some time not, also sometimes its getting executed only one time only.

```
public void CallTask()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = getdata(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() => StartTask(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["PackageId"])));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw;
    }
}

public async Task StartTask(string PackageId)
{
    int timegap = 30 * 1000;
    //module 1
    int Slice1 = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < Slice1; i++)
    {
        // this is api call which needs to be called at every 30 seconds,
        // for number of slices which can vary.
        var _response = await CallApi(PackageId); 

        SaveResultinDB(_response);

        await Task.Delay(timegap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `try`/`catch` block inside the `StartTask` method, and logging the errors?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes , no error was found , most of the times it is executing function only one time , not all iteration of loop.

Comment: You should also do error handling inside the lambda that you pass to the `Task.Run`: `Task.Run(() => { try { ... } catch { ... } });`. My guess is that your problem is related to this issue: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Btw launching operations in a fire-and-forget manner is [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335345/web-api-fire-and-forget) by the experts, but I guess that you have good reasons for doing it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for suggestion , I add lock in logging method which was adding log in txt file and now working fine