# Which TPL suits best for this scenario in .NET API ? Task/Threads

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have this method that increases the views of a video when it's watched.
If the video of the person who published it reaches 200 views, I send an congrats email to him,
but if the email sending DELAYS, I don't want the user to wait for that delay to watch the video.
I need to make Video loading not depend on email sending.
I have used Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew and inside it Parallell
I don't have experience with tasks/threads so which is the best way to implement it.

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<ViewedVideoDto>> AddVideoView(int candidateVideoId)
        {
            var video = await _dbcontext.CandidateFiles.Include(x=>x.Candidate).ThenInclude(x=>x.User).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == candidateVideoId);
            if (video is null)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<ViewedVideoDto>().NotFound(nameof(Resource.VideoEmpty), Resource.VideoEmpty);
            }
            video.VideoViews += 1;
            _dbcontext.Update(video);
            await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            if (video.VideoViews == 200)
            {
                //Method 1 
                await Task.Run(() =>
                   _candidateEmailService.Achieved200VideoViews(video.Candidate.User.Email,
                       video.Candidate.User.FullName));

                //Method 2
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                  {
                      _candidateEmailService.Achieved200VideoViews(video.Candidate.User.Email,
                          video.Candidate.User.FullName);
                  }));
                  
            }
            return new ServiceResponse<ViewedVideoDto>()
            {
                Data = new ViewedVideoDto()
                {
                    VideoId = video.Id
                }
            };
            

        }
```

```
 public async Task Achieved200VideoViews(string receiverEmail, string fullName)
    {
        var candidateTemplate = EmailTemplate.Return(EmailTemplateConst.CanEmailTempFolder, EmailTemplateConst.CanAchieved200VideoViews,fullName);
            
        var innoEmail = new InnoEmail()
        {
            Email = receiverEmail,
            Subject = "Touchpoint after 200 views",
            HtmlMessage = candidateTemplate 
        };
        await _emailService.SendAsync(innoEmail);
```

```
public async Task<bool> SendAsync(Email email)
        {
            try
            {
                var apiKey = _configuration.GetSection("SENDGRID_API_KEY").GetSection("SecretKey").Value;
                var Email = _configuration.GetSection("SENDGRID_API_KEY").GetSection("Email").Value;

                var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
                var msg = new SendGridMessage()
                {
                    From = new EmailAddress(Email, "test"),
                    Subject = email.Subject,
                    PlainTextContent = null,
                    HtmlContent = email.HtmlMessage
                };
                msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email.Email));

                var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);

                response.StatusCode.ToString();
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's impossible to give an answer without knowing what `Achieved200VideoViews` does but "Method 2" is a bug that wastes two threads to do what `Task.Run` would do. `dbcontext.Update(video);` isn't needed at all, DbContext tracks changes and already knows that `video` has changed. If you want to send an email without blocking the caller use a *queue* to send that request to a service, eg a BackgroundService

Comment: I included Achieved200VideoViews method and the email send service

Comment: Two questions related to fire-and-forget: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335345/web-api-fire-and-forget "Web Api - Fire and Forget"), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316504/proper-way-to-start-and-async-fire-and-forget-call "Proper way to start and async fire-and-forget call?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Method 1* (`await Task.Run(() =>`) will not achieve the declared goal because you are awaiting the result which basically will suspend the `AddVideoView` execution until the `Achieved200VideoViews` finishes. If you want fire-and-forget behaviour - remove the await.

Based on `Achieved200VideoViews` implementation, basically it just sends mail. I would say that it does not matter which one is better because both fire-and-forget approaches are not good enough: they lack observability (for example email sending can fail for multiple reasons or app will be restarted during the process).

I would suggest and approach similar to [transactional outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) - add either a flag to `video` table or separate table which will store info about notification about 200 views send (something like a `video.ToSend200ViewNotification`) and update that in `AddVideoView` and then process that table in some background job handler for example using [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) or Hangfire or Quartz (or add flag `Is200ViewNotificationSend` and process all videos with views >= 200 and `Is200ViewNotificationSend` set to false).

If you are ok with limitations of fire-and-forget approach for synchronous operations `Task.Run` should be preferable (without `await`). As written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-7.0) `TaskFactory.StartNew` is more suitable for more complicated scenarios (also it is not task-aware and in "ordinary" cases will not handle methods returning `Task`'s correctly):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the `Task.Run` method is the recommended way to launch a compute-bound task. Use the `StartNew` method only when you require fine-grained control for a long-running, compute-bound task. This includes scenarios in which you want to control the following:

> - `Task` creation options. Tasks created by the `Task.Run` method by default are created with the `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` option. To override this behavior, or to provide other `TaskCreationOptions` options, call a `StartNew` overload.
> - Parameter passing. The overloads of the `Task.Run` method do not allow you to pass a parameter to the task delegate. Overloads of the `StartNew` method do.
> - The task scheduler. The overloads of the `Task.Run` method use the default task scheduler. To control the task scheduler, call a `StartNew` overload with a scheduler parameter. For more information, see `TaskScheduler`.

But since your `Achieved200VideoViews` method already returns `Task` and assuming it is "truly async" then just skipping `await` on the invokation should be fine to achieve fire-and-forget functionality (and I would say it is preferable because it should be less resource-consuming):

```cs
_ = _candidateEmailService.Achieved200VideoViews(video.Candidate.User.Email,
                       video.Candidate.User.FullName);
```

Comment: *"both [...] are basically fire-and-forget methods"* -- As far as I can see the "Method 1" in OP's code is awaiting the `Task.Run` call, so why is it fire-and-forget?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, missed that. Assumed that OP required not waiting for the result. Will fix answer a bit later.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias despite it awaiting the `Task.Run` call it seems that method is actually fire-and-forget =))

Comment: The `Task.Run` unwraps asynchronous delegates. See [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/). So the `Task.Run` task will complete when the asynchronous delegate completes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes. I even wrote about `StartNew` not handling correctly tasks) Too late for today to do something meaningful)