# Should I await asynchronous SaveToDb method when I dont need the result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Is it recommended to await "_teamRepository.AddTeamToDbAsync(teamToAdd)" method? Its just for saving to db no further validations etc. If I dont await save operation I provide faster result but are there some risks I am not aware of?

```cs
public async Task<OperationResult<TeamDto>> AddTeamAsync(TeamForCreationDto team)
        {
            var teamToAdd = _mapper.Map<Team>(team);
            bool IsNameTaken = await CheckIfTeamExistsAsync(team.Name);

            if (IsNameTaken)
            {
                return new OperationResult<TeamDto>
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    ErrorMessage = "Provided name is already taken.",
                    HttpResponseCode = 409
                };
            }
            else
            {
                _teamRepository.AddTeamToDbAsync(teamToAdd);          // HERE
                var teamToReturn = _mapper.Map<TeamDto>(teamToAdd);
                return new OperationResult<TeamDto>
                {
                    IsSuccess = true,
                    Data = teamToReturn,
                    HttpResponseCode = 201
                };
            }
        }
```

Let me know what you think and if I understand it correctly

Comment: If you don't await the call, it could fail and you would report IsSuccess = true to the caller even though that was not the case.

Comment: Related: [Web Api - Fire and Forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335345/web-api-fire-and-forget).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `await` it.

If you do not, then your code will return success before the operation is successful. Some validations like unique and foreign key constraints are checked *during the save* and cannot be known to be successful until after the save completes.

Furthermore, the normal pattern is to dispose the db context when the controller action completes; this may cancel the save (after a successful response is returned).

Finally, any time you have code that outlives a request, it may be terminated without warning any time the host shuts down (e.g., during a rolling upgrade).