# C# Differences between Result and ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

What are the differences between this two methods that seems to do the same thing? Can it be done even with async/await?

```
public Task<int> TaskMaxAsync1 ( Task<int>[] my_ints )
{
    return Task.WhenAll( my_ints )
    .ContinueWith ( x => x.Result.Where ( i => i%2 != 0 ).Max( ) ) ;
}

public Task<int> TaskMaxAsync2 ( Task<int>[] my_ints )
{
    var numbers = Task.WhenAll( my_ints ).Result ;
    return Task.FromResult( numbers.Where( i => i%2 != 0 ).Max( ) ) ;
}
```

Comment: One difference would be that the one using `.Result` is prone to deadlocking - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen They both use .Result

Comment: Agh, yes, ok, let me reword. The one using `.Result` outside of `ContinueWith` (ie. the second one) is prone to deadlocking. The only place it is safe to read `.Result` is from a task that is guaranteed to have completed. Reading `.Result` from a task that has not yet completed may deadlock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Differences between Result and ContinueWith

`Result` will synchronously block until the task completes, and will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

`ContinueWith` will register a callback with the task, and invoke that callback when the task completes.

For asynchronous code, both `Result` and `ContinueWith` should be replaced by `await`.

> Can it be done even with async/await?

Sure, like this:

```
public async Task<int> MaxAsync(Task<int>[] my_ints)
{
  int[] ints = await Task.WhenAll(my_ints);
  return ints.Where(i => i % 2 != 0).Max();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> What are the differences between this two methods that seems to do the
>   same thing?

The difference is that the former returns a hot task to the caller, while the latter synchronously blocks, then re-wraps the result in a `Task` using `Task.FromResult`. The latter is also a common case for **deadlocks**, if you're running inside an environment that has a custom `SynchronizationContext`.

> Can it be done even with async/await?

Yes, it can:

```
public async Task<int> MaxAsync(Task<int>[] myInts)
{
    int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(myInts);
    return results.Max(i => i % 2 != 0 ? i : (int?)null) ?? 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`task0.Result` will synchronously block and wait for `task0` to complete, while `task1.ContinueWith` will not wait for `task1` to complete but returns a new `Task`(which will run when `task1` completes) immediately.

So, the two methods in your example do not behave the same. In your second method, if `my_ints` were not all ran to complete when they were passed to the `WhenAll` method, the `.Result` will synchronously block the calling thread for whatever long time that all tasks within `my_ints` would take to finish, and if some of them throws exception, `TaskMaxAsync2` throws.

However the first method will return immediately even `my_ints` would never finish or throw exception.