# Unit Testing Async Methods Using NUnit and C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test an async methods of a search query. The unit test is defined below:

```
[Test]
public async Task MyTest1()
{
    var readyToScheduleQuery = new ReadyToScheduleQuery()
    {
        Facets = new List<Facet>() 
                 {  
                     new Facet() 
                     {
                         Name = "Service Type", 
                         Values = new List<FacetValue>()
                                  {  
                                      new FacetValue() 
                                      {  
                                          Value = "SomeJob", 
                                          Selected = true
                                      } 
                                  } 
                     } 
                 }
    };

    var result = readyToScheduleQuery.ExecuteAsync(_appointmentRespositoryStub); 

    Assert.IsNotNull(result); 
}
```

The `ExecuteAsync` method of readyToScheduleQuery is defined below:

```
internal async Task<ReadyToScheduleResult> ExecuteAsync(IAppointmentRepository appointments)
{
    var query = await appointments.GetReadyToSchedule(this.Id, exclude: NotificationTags.Something);
```

The unit test just hangs up and never returns a result. Any ideas?

It hangs up if I do the following: (Note the `Result` property at the end)

```
var result = readyToScheduleQuery.ExecuteAsync(_appointmentRespositoryStub).Result;
```

Comment: The first problem I see is that 'result' isn't a ReadyToScheduleResult object - it is a Task<ReadyToScheduleResult> which means your IsNotNull assertion will pass. You need to await it. Are you sure that GetReadyToSchedule returns?

Comment: Yes, When I try to access .Result which contains the actual object. The unit test hangs and does not return.

Comment: I think GetReadyToSchedule is hanging up. Test this by taking it out of the test - try var query = await Task<ReadyToScheduleResult>.FromResult(null)

Comment: It seems like it is hanging on the mocked respository.

Comment: Before you fix your repository, do two things: First sort out the awaits in THIS test. Then write tests for your mock repository to verify your fixes

Comment: @johndoe: Update NUnit if you haven't done so recently, and note the compiler warning on your unit test method.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an await. When writing your async/await you continue to call await on everything that is marked as async all the way down your callstack.

```
[Test]
public async Task MyTest1()
{
    var readyToScheduleQuery = new ReadyToScheduleQuery()
    {
        Facets = new List<Facet>() {  new Facet() {  Name = "Service Type", Values = new List<FacetValue>() {  new FacetValue() {  Value = "SomeJob", Selected = true} } } }                 
    };

    // missing await
    var result = await readyToScheduleQuery.ExecuteAsync(_appointmentRespositoryStub); 

    Assert.IsNotNull(result); // you will receive your actual expected unwrapped result here. test it directly, not the task.
}
```

This will hang.

```
var result = readyToScheduleQuery.ExecuteAsync(_appointmentRespositoryStub).Result;
```

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17248813/1260204) from Stephen Cleary as to why that is. Here again that answer (*refer to the link though in case it has changed since the writing of this answer*).

> You're running into the standard deadlock situation that I describe on my blog and in an MSDN article: the async method is attempting to schedule its continuation onto a thread that is being blocked by the call to Result.
>
> In this case, your SynchronizationContext is the one used by NUnit to execute async void test methods. I would try using async Task test methods instead.