# System exception when using httpclient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a problem with my universal app project (Universal Windows 8.1). I want to download a string which I then deserialize to a classes. But I encourage a problem with downloading this string on windows phone. I have a separate lib. Where I have only httpclient which downloads string and then deserialize it to classes. Everything works fine (tests are green), but when I plug it into windows phone app project. It looks like, it goes inside library code, but doesn't download anything..
I move code to download string to a windows phone solution to check why it doesn't work. But right now I'm constantly getting an exception like this:

```
System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F30
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at ProjectName.Mobile.MainPage.<InitComboBoxes>d__10.MoveNext()
```

Here is my code:

```
private HttpClient client;
private CancellationTokenSource cts;
private HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter;

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    client = new HttpClient(filter);
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await InitComboBoxes();
}

private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    filter?.Dispose();
    client?.Dispose();
    cts?.Dispose();
}

private async Task InitComboBoxes()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(@"http://planer.info.pl/api/rest/places.json")).AsTask(cts.Token);
        var t = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().AsTask(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var msg = new MessageDialog("Please check Your internet connection!" + e.Message);
        await msg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Right now I don't have any idea how to resolve this problem.. If anyone could help me I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I don't see anything particularly wrong with it (and I didn't test it); except:

- `HttpResponseMessage` is `IDisposable` so you should consider Disposing that also.

But, this is just some criticism :P

Looking at the Exception, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298646.aspx) the issue is that you cannot connect to the server.

> ERROR_WINHTTP_NO_CM_CONNECTION
>
> 0x80072F30
>
> There was a problem connecting to the server.

There are many ways that this issue can arrise:

- Certificate
- Firewall
- Server is off

When working with Phone make sure that the Time on the phone is setup correctly (I've seen this causing a lot of issues)

#### it goes inside library code, but doesn't download anything..

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you mean it goes in and does not return then I suspect a threading [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks).

Hope this helps.

Comment: "HttpResponseMessage is IDisposable so you should consider Disposing that also." Good catch! I will check what You propose..

Comment: Your answer target me to what is wrong. I forget to set up a internet connection on phone. This is why every tests passed, but I don't get response on phone...
Many Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get data from url then try this code. Unless there is a reason this doesn't suit your needs?

```
    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync("http://planer.info.pl/api/rest/places.json").Result;
                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

String response = await GetData();
```

Comment: Even shorter: `return await client.GetStringAsync(...)`.