# Finalizer for Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How do I add a finalizer that runs once all parallels have completed?

```
Parallel.ForEach(entries, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15 }, async (entry) =>
    // Do something with the entry.
});
```

I have tried like this but it doesn't compile:

```
Parallel.ForEach(entries, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15 }, async (entry) =>
    // Do something with the entry.
}, () => { // Was hoping this would work. });
```

Comment: Parallel.ForEach does ***NOT*** work correctly when you do `async (entry) =>`, Do not use async methods with it. You must use non async methods or switch to somthing that does like [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't have an overload for a function returning `Task`, so your async function is just going to return immediately and the iteration will complete near-immediately.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallell-foreach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should **not** declare the action for the `Parallel.ForEach` as `async`. If you use an `await` inside that action, the control flow is returned to `Parallel.ForEach` and its implementation "thinks" that the action is *finished*. This will lead to a very *different behaviour than you expect*.
2. The call to `Parallel.ForEach` returns **when the loop is completed**. It returns when all actions have been done for all the elements in the enumeration. So whatever you want to do "when all parallels have completed" can be done right after that call:

   ```
   Parallel.ForEach(entries, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15 }, 
            (entry) =>
            // Do something with the entry.
   );
   DoSomethingWhenAllParallelsHaveCompleted();
   ```

Comment: How would I await inside of the action then? I need to use an `HttpClient` to send data, and it has a `SendAsync` method on it.

Comment: @Alexandru You would need to use `.Wait()` or `.Result` instead. Just do it synchronous.

Comment: Can you provide an example? `.Result` can deadlock, and I am not sure if `.Wait()` guarantees a result afterwards? This `async` shit is a mess.

Comment: @Alexandru actually `async` is really cool, it's just hard to combine with "normal" threads and `Parallel`. An example is hard to give as it depends on what you are really doing. I can't even see why `.Result` should lead to a deadlock where you're `async` should have worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks

Comment: @Alexandru Use [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx), a your Parallel.ForEach is a `new ActionBlock<Entry>(async (entry) => ..., new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15 })`

Comment: @Alexandru as I said, it depends on what you are doing. Parallel or asynchronous execution can boil your brain...as a 3k user you know that this is a Q&A site, so maybe you start a new question about your specific problems with that action, as this is getting too broad to discuss in comments.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks Scott, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do anything. Your `Parallel.ForEach` will run until all threads have finished their work. Thats one of the really nice benefits the `Parallel.Foreach()` has.

So right after `Parallel.ForEach(() => { /* code */ });` all threads will be finished.

Answer (score 1):

As I and others mentioned in comments `Parallel.ForEach` does not support async functions the reason is when you did `async (entry) => ...` that is the same as

```
Parallel.ForEach(entries, Example);

//elsewhere
async void Example(Entry entry)
{
   ...
}
```

Because the function is `async void` the `ForEach` can't tell when a function is "done" so it will just think it is done when you hit the first `await` instead of when the task finishes.

The way to fix this is to use a library that can suport async functions, [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good one. You get it by installing the NuGet package to your project [`Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow). You could recreate your previous code as

```
private const int MAX_PARALLELISM = 15

public async Task ProcessEntries(IEnumerable<Entry> entries)
{
    var block = new ActionBlock<Entry>(async (entry) => 
                                       {
                                           //This is now a "async Task" instead of a async void
                                       }, 
                                       new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
                                       { 
                                           MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MAX_PARALLELISM

                                       });
    foreach(var entry in entries)
    {
        await block.SendAsync(entry);
    }

    block.Complete();
    await block.Completion;

    DoExtraWorkWhenDone();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this bit of advice, it will go a long, long way. This is exactly what I was looking for. Even beyond that, this is what `Task` should have had all along.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote you more. I was having one of the worst days I've ever had at work, with hyenas breathing down my neck every few seconds for status updates, meanwhile I was trying to concentrate on writing some quality code. So, ultimately my thanks to you Scott, you saved my life today. Sometimes people don't realize the extent of the impacts they can have on others, but this was huge. Thanks again, man. Just wanted to share that with you :)

Comment: A follow up to this is how people can make use of and leverage `Func<Task>` within TPL blocks: http://www.dima.to/blog/?p=322 and this is also a good read: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate