# Running AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp

I am trying to assign a HLS stream to a `MediaElement` and then play it immediately but I'm failing to do so.

It's an UWP application (Windows 10).

```
Uri hlsUri = new Uri("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8");
AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationResult hlsSource = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(hlsUri);

if (hlsSource .Status == AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
{
    videoPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(hlsSource .MediaSource);
    videoPlayer.Play();
}
```

For some reason this thing doesn't work. The StreamSource is set, but for some reason the `Play()` is executed before that.

I tried to wrap the `CreateFromUriAsync` method in a `Task`, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks/32429753#32429753), to wait for the result first, but I couldn't make it work.

It works with `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));`, but that looks to me like a ticking timebomb. However, it leads me to believe, that my problem is somewhere in the `async` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inmediately start playing after the `MediaElement` is set, I would suggest you to put its `AutoPlay` property to true. This should work! :)

Comment: Well, i guess that should work. It's still strange, that `Play()` is executed before the setting of the Media Source.

Comment: That"s because the creation of the `AdaptiveMediaSource` is asynchronous and awaited. Another thing you could is running the creation in a thread and wait until it finishes, for example using `Task.Run()` but I think it doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Stefan please mark the answer as the solution if it has solved your issue :)

Comment: Sure. It's a workaround, but it really is the easiest way out of this sticky situation. :)