# NewsAPI C# library runs on console, hangs on winforms

Tags: c#, .net

I ran the example given at the web site under Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and it worked fine.  However, when I attempted to run it on a winforms library, it hung, even when given the exact same term:

Console Version

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var newsApiClient = new NewsApiClient("KeyRedacted");
    var articlesResponse = newsApiClient.GetEverything(new EverythingRequest
    {
        Q = "Apple",
        SortBy = SortBys.Popularity,
        Language = Languages.EN,
        From = new DateTime(2018, 10, 16)
    });
    if (articlesResponse.Status == Statuses.Ok)
    {

    //code here
```

Winforms Version

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newsApiClient = new NewsApiClient("keyredacted");
    var articleResponse = newsApiClient.GetEverything(new EverythingRequest
    {
        Q = "Apple",
        SortBy = SortBys.Popularity,
        Language = Languages.EN,
        From = new DateTime(2018, 10, 16)
    });  //this is where it hangs

    if (articleResponse.Status == Statuses.Ok)
    {
```

Comment: What is NewsAPI? Is this something you wrote?

Comment: is the `NewsApiClient` constructor case sensitive? `KeyRedacted` vs `keyredacted`

Comment: Does 'NewsApiClient' use any async code - especially: Is 'GetEverything' calling any async code?

Comment: This is the URL for newsapi https://github.com/News-API-gh/News-API-csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [this client](https://github.com/News-API-gh/News-API-csharp), the [method you're calling](https://github.com/News-API-gh/News-API-csharp/blob/ff4a118e1511ff7c32a60dc1341d81f91d518bdc/NewsAPI/NewsApiClient.cs#L179) uses a `Task.Result` which can [cause a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17248813/86860). Seems reasonable, since the code/signature and examples match.

I would rewrite your code like this for WinForms:

```
private async void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newsApiClient = new NewsApiClient("keyredacted");
    var articleResponse = await newsApiClient.GetEverythingAsync(new EverythingRequest
    ...
```

If you are deadset on not using the async methods in your code you could try running it inside of a `Task.Run(() => /* stuff */);`

See also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/