# Async/Await blocking on Task.WhenAll is called in Sitecore MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, sitecore, restsharp, multitasking

I have to call a restsharp ExecuteTaskAsync, I have used `await` while executing the API and await to complete all tasks since it runs in loop, as soon as it hits `await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(tasksList)`, then no it's blocked, no response in it.

Calling Async code:

```cs
Task<IEnumerable<AsyncResponse>> responseList = AddPAsync(id, id1);
```

To Execute Restsharp's ExecuteTaskAsync:

```cs
public static async Task<AsyncResponse> ExecuteApiAsync(RestRequest request, string url, dynamic identifier)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient(url);
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var restResponse = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

    return new AsyncResponse{ RestResponse = restResponse, Identifier = identifier };
}
```

Preparing request and calling RestSharp's ExecuteTaskAsync:

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<AsyncResponse>> AddPAsync(List<Participant> participantInfo, string registrationId)
{
    foreach (var p in pinfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(Constants.API_VERSION + Uri, Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
            request.AddParameter(Constants.APP_JSON, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p), ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = Util.ExecuteApiAsync(request, Constants.END_POINT_URL_NAME, p.Identifier);
            tasksList.Add(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(tasksList);
}
```

When it hits `await Task.WhenAll` then no response.
I have already tried:
`ConfigureAwait(false)  - it is not working.
It is ASP.Net MVC application in sitecore.

Comment: Should it not be `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: `async` is just syntactic sugar and `await` doesn't *block*. It awaits *without blocking* for an already executing task to finish before resuming on the original synchronization context. If that task doesn't finish, `await` won't return.

Comment: @Dumisani *that* would block, while `await Task.WhenAll()` *doesn't* block

Comment: Oh, understood.

Comment: Well, you do not have `await` in that `Task<IEnumerable<AsyncResponse>> responseList = AddPAsync(id, id1);`, do you. Do you also `await` the `responseList` later?

Comment: Task.WaitAll is also not working

Comment: @AbhishekJain `Task.WaitAll` is *a blocking call*. `await Task.WhenAll` isn't. And you don't *await* the call to `AddPAsync` so there's no possibility of blocking there either. The code you posted doesn't show anything that could block, although it *does* show a possibly runaway task whose results aren't used by anyone. The action that calls `AddPAsync` would return before that method had a chance to finish.

Comment: I tried with only one request, instead of loop, that also did not work

Comment: Do you have blocking calls anywhere *further up* your call stack?

Comment: @StephenCleary - No this is the only async call, no where WhenAll or WaitAll is used apart from this

Comment: @AbhishekJain: If the calling method isn't `async`, then how is this method called?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Where AddPAsync is called, that method is not async method, AddPAsync is async method which in turn calls ExecuteApiAsync method. Anything wrong?

Comment: @AbhishekJain Pretty much. How do you then get the result of that async `AddPAsync` method called from a non-async method? By [using `responseList.Result`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17248680/11683)?

Comment: @GSerg: Yes ,
Task<IEnumerable<AsyncResponse>> responseList = AddPAsync(id, id1);
            if (responseList != null)
            {
                foreach (var restResponse in responseList.Result)
                {

Comment: Possible duplicate of [await works but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)

Comment: @GSerg: Yes, if i remove .Result, it does not hang, but how do i get the Result to iterate?

Comment: By using `await responseList`.

Comment: To answer to your next question, *"But then the calling method also has to be async"*, - that [would be correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Alternatively, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9343594/11683.

Comment: @GSerg: Adding AsyncContext from Nito.AsyncEx worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding AsyncContext from Nito.AsyncEx worked.