# Timeout issue with PostAsJsonAsync .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, web-services, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, connection-timeout

I am calling a web api through a dll file which is being used by .net client desktop application. Dll file is written in `.Net 4.0`.

Sometimes I get frequent errors on this line.

```
var postResponse = client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, Input).Result;
```

After the error message i check IIS and web service log files. As per the log files, the above line of code didn't get to web service because web method logs all activities in its own log file.

Is there a way to avoid timeout errors.

**Dll file code**

```
 private T CallService<T>(string path)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = EndpointAddress;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, Input).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var serviceResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;

               // return service response;
            } 
            else
            {
               // return default (T)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Web Service Method**

```
       [HttpPost]
        public CusResponse GetCustomer(CustomerOperationInput input)
        {


        }
```

**Here is the header data when it times out**

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Connection: close
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 11:06:45 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 36
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

**Error from IIS trace file**

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-230F-008000000019}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ManagedPipelineHandler</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">128</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Internal Server Error</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `client.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite`?

Comment: Also take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) of the `HttpClient` class: *`HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an `HttpClient` class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads.*

Comment: `.Result` is wrong. You shouldn't access an async `Result` like this, it can cause deadlocking. Which I'd imagine is your issue here. `CallService` should be `async` and you should call this method using `await`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await works but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)

Comment: aren't async tasks only supported in .Net Framework 4.5 onwards.

Comment: HttpClient was added in 4.5. You're already working with 4.5, so why use all those blocking calls?  4.0 is *not* supported anyway. 4.5 came out *7* years ago. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2 It's high time you upgraded to a current version

Comment: No I am not working with 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a timeout. A timeout means: "I have given up waiting because I got no response".

However, you got a response from the server. The fact that you have "header data" at all shows that. The reply was [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). That will happen automatically in ASP.NET when an unhandled exception is thrown, but it can also be explicitly sent. Either way, it means something bad happened.

The `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`, so the body of the response may have an error message that you can use to figure out what went wrong.

So read the body of the response.

Comment: i have added some info from the IIS trace log to my question.

Comment: The body of the response (`response.Content`) would be more useful.

Comment: what info you like to see from response.content? content has header  and then header has some info.

Comment: What does `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` show you when you see the 500 error?

Comment: its there at the bottom of my question

Comment: Which part? I see "header data", "IIS trace logs", and a screenshot that doesn't show the content of the `Content` stream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201957/discussion-between-user1263981-and-gabriel-luci).

Comment: I got this Id = 4197, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"

Comment: So there is your error message: "An error has occurred". Unfortunately not descriptive, but the point is that's it's an error in the API. If you aren't the one who maintains that API, then you need to ask whoever is for help.