# How to execute a dynamic list of async functions in a sequential way?

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, task, .net-core-3.1

I have refactored a Web API to rely on async/await in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I have the following scenario: a statistics method is sequentially computing a list of indicators which are defined in a list.

```
readonly Dictionary<StatisticItemEnum, Func<Task<SimpleStatisticItemApiModel>>> simpleItemActionMap =
    new Dictionary<StatisticItemEnum, Func<Task<SimpleStatisticItemApiModel>>>();

private void InitSimpleStatisticFunctionsMap()
{
    simpleItemActionMap.Add(StatisticItemEnum.AllQuestionCount, GetAllQuestionCountApiModel);
    simpleItemActionMap.Add(StatisticItemEnum.AllAnswerCount, GetAllAnswerCountApiModel);
    simpleItemActionMap.Add(StatisticItemEnum.AverageAnswer, GetAverageAnswer);
    // other mappings here
}

private async Task<SimpleStatisticItemApiModel> GetAllQuestionCountApiModel()
{
    // await for database operation
}

private async Task<SimpleStatisticItemApiModel> GetAllAnswerCountApiModel()
{
    // await for database operation
}

private async Task<SimpleStatisticItemApiModel> GetAverageAnswer()
{
    // await for database operation
}
```

The code sequentially goes through each item and computes it and after the refactoring it is looking like this:

```
itemIds.ForEach(itemId =>
{
    var itemEnumValue = (StatisticItemEnum) itemId;
    if (simpleItemActionMap.ContainsKey(itemEnumValue))
    {
        var result = simpleItemActionMap[itemEnumValue]().Result;
        payload.SimpleStatisticItemModels.Add(result);
    }
});
```

I know that `Task.Result` [might lead to deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks), but I could not find any other way to make this work.

**Question:** How to execute a dynamic list of async functions in a sequential way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `ForEach` call to a regular `foreach`, and then you can use `await`:

```
foreach (var itemId in itemIds)
{
  var itemEnumValue = (StatisticItemEnum) itemId;
  if (simpleItemActionMap.ContainsKey(itemEnumValue))
  {
    var result = await simpleItemActionMap[itemEnumValue]();
    payload.SimpleStatisticItemModels.Add(result);
  }
}
```

Do not make the `ForEach` lambda `async`; that will result in an `async void` method, and you should [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: yes, my final solution is indeed using `foreach` instead of `ForEach` to simplify things. Now I also understand that it is the only way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
itemIds.ForEach(async itemId =>
{
    var itemEnumValue = (StatisticItemEnum) itemId;
    if (simpleItemActionMap.ContainsKey(itemEnumValue))
    {
        var result = await simpleItemActionMap[itemEnumValue]();
        payload.SimpleStatisticItemModels.Add(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried using await, but I simply could figure out where the `async` was missing. Of course, on the lambda expression / "closure" itself. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it helped.