# Calling an async method with `.Result` in a Linq expression causes deadlock

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, async-await

We ran into a bug where we had to validate a list of objects with an async method. The writer of the code wanted to just stuff it into a Linq expression like so:

```
var invalidObjects = list
      .Where(x => _service.IsValidAsync(x).Result)
      .ToList();
```

The validating method looked something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> IsValidAsync(object @object) {
  var validObjects = await _cache.GetAsync<List<object>>("ValidObjectsCacheKey");

  return validObjects.Contains(@object);
}
```

This little solution caused the whole application to hang on the `await _cache.GetAsync` line.
The cache is a distributed cache (redis).
After changing the linq to a simple foreach and properly awaiting `_service.IsValidAsync`, the code ran deadlock-free and basically in an instant.

I understand on a basic level how `async-await` works, but I can't wrap my head around why this happened especially because the list only had one object.

Any suggestion is welcome!

EDIT: The application is running on .net Core 2.2, but the library in which the problem happened is targeting .netstandard 2.0.
`System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` returns null at the time of the deadlock

EDIT2: It turns changing the cache provider (but still accessing it via an async method) also resolves the issue, so the bug might actually be in the redis cache client:
https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis/RedisCache.cs

Comment: There are a few basic rules regarding async/await, and one of the key ones is never call `.Result` unless you have `await`ed it previously (I'm simplifying the rules drastically).

Comment: Is it an AspNet or an AspNet Core application?

Comment: It's Asp.net Core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await works but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)

Comment: calling an `async` method synchronously will cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already stated issue of mixing async-await and blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()`

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

> To summarize this second guideline, you should avoid mixing async and blocking code. Mixed async and blocking code can cause deadlocks, more-complex error handling and unexpected blocking of context threads. The exception to this guideline is the Main method for console applications, or—if you’re an advanced user—managing a partially asynchronous codebase.

Sometimes the simple approach, as you have already discovered, is to traverse the list and properly await the asynchronous function

For example

```
var invalidObjects = //...

foreach(var x in list){
    if(!(await _service.IsValidAsync(x)))
        invalidObjects.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what we did, and it worked. I'm more interested as why the original solution was bad. I'll read the doc you sent :)

Comment: @TamásSzabó check included link

Comment: So basically the context was waiting for `_service.IsValidAsync(x).Result` to finish, which was waiting for `_cache.GetAsync` to finish, which was waiting for the context to give it resources? And we have full circle?

Comment: In AspNet Core there is no synchronization context used. Means this deadlock won't happen.

Comment: @JánosPánczél any other ideas then?

Comment: If you don't play with SynchronizationContext (what is quiet tricky) or you maybe use vanilla Asp instead of Core, I can't see any scenario your code end up in deadlock.
Edit: maybe copy the code to a console application and see if it works there. If it does, you might use vanilla Asp.

Comment: @TamásSzabó does any of the code surrounding the shown snippet use await?

Comment: If this is really ASP.NET Core, there's no SynchronizationContext, unless one was added by some library.

Comment: I've removed the quote mentioning SynchronizationContext to avoid any confusion

Comment: It definitely is dotnet core.
@Nkosi The whole method which contains the snippet is async.

Comment: @TamásSzabó can you run the exact same code from console application or unit test? Even by simply calling the controller's action in a unit test or copy the whole code into a console application. If it runs fine, somewhere, something adds SynchronizationContext into the process.

Comment: @JánosPánczél Sure, I'll post the results