# How can I post an order by API

Tags: c#, api, post, sample, binance

I wrote a sample code to test Binance Api :

```
 var apiClient = new ApiClient("API-Key", "API-Secret");
 var binanceClient = new BinanceClient(apiClient);
```

But program hangs when run the below method :

```
var buyOrder = binanceClient.PostNewOrder("ethbtc", 1m, 0.045m, OrderSide.BUY).Result;
```

Comment: From what of application are you calling this async method synchronously?

Comment: I wrote this code in C# (windows Application)

Comment: Did you mean WinForms or WPF or UWP or ???

Comment: I use Winforms to develop program

Comment: The `.Result` is causing a deadlock. The UI thread is waiting for the async I/O operation to complete and the `.Result` is waiting for the UI thread to be able to continue its work. That's why it is hanging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['await' works, but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)