# Asynchronous Unit Testing - async/await vs. Task.Result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, nunit

My solution architect and I were discussing the correct way to unit test the asynchronous code.

He prefers using `void [Test]` methods, and asserting `Task.Result`, while I feel that asynchronous methods should be tested with `async/await [Test]` methods.

Somehow, I feel that using Task.Result is incorrect way to testing the asynchronous code, but can't justify or pin-point exactly why?

For example, given the below code:

```
    public class SomeService 
    {
        public async Task<bool> ProcessSomething(string request)
        {
           return await Repository.Save(request);
        }
    }
```

**Method 1: Task.Result**

```
    [Test]
    public void ServiceProcessTest()
    {          
       var sut = new SomeService();

       // Use Task.Result
       var unusedResult= sut.ProcessSomething("Hello world!").Result;
       
       A.CallTo(() => Repository.Save(A<string>>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
    }
```

**Method 2: async/await**

```
    [Test]
    public async Task ServiceProcessTest()
    {          
       var sut = new SomeService();

       // Use async/await
       var unusedResult= await sut.ProcessSomething("Hello world!");
       
       A.CallTo(() => Repository.Save(A<string>>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
    }
```

Which once should we be using, and why?
If both are correct, then are there times when one is preferred over the other?

Comment: `async-await` is the documented practice, as `Task.Result` can cause deadlock

Comment: [Async Programming : Unit Testing Asynchronous Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/november/async-programming-unit-testing-asynchronous-code)

Comment: Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: As with any aspect of any method, you should test it the way you use it, else your test isn't helping you verify that it will work properly in the cases you care about.  If your tests are testing different behavior than your production code uses, then the tests aren't adding any value.

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes I did look at the Microsoft documentation, however it didn't deny using Task.Result (or I might have missed it).

Comment: What @Servy said. :-) Make the choice in your production code and then echo it in your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, always use `async/await` if you can, since `Task.Result` [can cause deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17248813/2877982). Also, the unit test should reflect how you use the `System Under Test` (SUT) from production code.

The *only* circumstance when you should use `Task.Result` IMO, is when introducing a function/object that returns a `Task` in *legacy code* and you aren't in the position (yet) to make the calling method `async`, so you are forced to use `Task.Result` to execute the `Task`.