# Activator.CreateInstance - MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'xxx' not found

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have the following code 
**Driver Code**

```cs
var provider = DataManager.BuildDatabase<FileDatabase>(config,false,dbPath).Result;
```

`DataManager.cs`

```cs
 public static async Task<IStorageProvider> BuildDatabase<TStorageProvider>(DbConfig config,
    bool isBuildUniqueAddress = false,params object[] buildParam) where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider
{
    var t = typeof(TStorageProvider);
    //merging params
    var buildConfig= new DbData(config);
    buildParam= buildParam.ToList().Prepend(buildConfig).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine($"Building Database of type:{t.FullName}");
   
    IStorageProvider? storageProvider = (IStorageProvider?)Activator.CreateInstance(t,buildParam);
}
```

and Here is my Constructor for type FileDatabase
`FileDatabase.cs`

```
public FileDatabase(DbConfig config,string dbPath)
{
    _dbData = new DbData(config);
    DbPath=dbPath;

    if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        Flush().RunSynchronously();
    }
}
```

When I try to execute code above, it gives me: 
`MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'assertUpdaterRefactor.StorageProvider.FileDatabase' not found.`\

I tried to debug content of variable `buildParam`
[image].
The debugger shows the buildParam is an object array and exactly matches the constructor. I just can't figure out the reason causing this problem. Please help
**UPDATE:** 
When I tried to create a new object array. The issue fixed magically
 `IStorageProvider? storageProvider = (IStorageProvider?)Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[]{config,"someStringValue"});`
Here is the original code copied from above just for reference 
 `IStorageProvider? storageProvider = (IStorageProvider?)Activator.CreateInstance(t,buildParam);`

I want to know the causes and why the original code does not work.

Comment: If an answer solved your question, make sure to mark it as answer so people can see that the question has ben solved

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of the `FileDatabase` is `DbConfig`, in your `BuildDatabase` you use a type `DbData`.

So instead of passing an instance of `var buildConfig= new DbData(config);` pass the config directly.

Would be something like:

```
public static async Task<IStorageProvider> BuildDatabase<TStorageProvider>(DbConfig config,
            bool isBuildUniqueAddress = false,params object[] buildParam) where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider
{

    var t = typeof(TStorageProvider);
    //merging params
    buildParam= buildParam.ToList().Prepend(config).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine($"Building Database of type:{t.FullName}");
   
    IStorageProvider? storageProvider = (IStorageProvider?)Activator.CreateInstance(t,buildParam);
 
}
```

Comment: also .Result can lead to a deadlock, try to use await on async methods. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17248813/18278998

Comment: How about `DataManager.BuildDatabase<FileDatabase>(config,false,dbPath).GetAwaiter().GetResult() ` ? Because sometimes I need to encapsulate async method into normal method ,for example, in object constructor,