# ASP.NET Core large file upload StreamContent vs MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I know there are lots of resources and answers about uploading large files in ASP.NET Core Web API, but my question is very specific and I couldn't find any answer.

I am trying to implement the Upload large file ability in an ASP.NET Core 7 API project. The difference I am having is I am not using a Web application as the UI, but rather a Winforms application is trying to upload the file.

All of the resources on the web mention using `MultipartReader` but I am trying to find the reason if it is required if the call is made from a Winforms desktop app.

When I make a request like this with a `StreamContent`;

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(sampleFilePath))
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream))
{
    var requestUrl = @"Document/UploadDocument";

    var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl , streamContent).Result;
}
```

I can upload a file sized 1,5 Gb.

I can also use :

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(sampleFilePath))
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream ))
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formData.Add(streamContent, "Files", "SampleDoc.pdf");

    var requestUrl = @"Document/UploadStream";

    var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, formData).Result;
}
```

EDIT :

Controller Actions :
For 1st one with `streamContent`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadDocument()
{
    var filePath = PathHelper.GetPath();    
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        Request.Body.CopyToAsync(fileStream).Wait();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

For 2nd one with `MultipartReader`

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipartFormData]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadStream()
{

    var fileUploadSummary = await _fileService.UploadFileAsync(HttpContext.Request.Body, Request.ContentType);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(UploadStream), fileUploadSummary);
}
```

NOTE: `_fileService` and `UploadFileAsync` implementations are  taken from this link : [https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-upload-large-files/][1]

My question is if both can upload the file, should I still use the second option with `MultipartReader` what is the advantage of it?

Comment: Show us your Controller Action method.

Comment: You are sending a MIME attachment.  Each attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  See sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  You are sending an http request/response which follows the RFC specifications for HTTP.  There are many libraries that can be used to send/receive HTTP.  The libraries methods may work work different but always has to meet the RFC.   The c# HTTP client is one of these libraries.  The Web library and the Winform libraries have different methods, but still must meet the RFC.

Comment: `var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, formData).Result;` <-- **Don't do this** - you **must** `await` the Task, never call `.Result` before doing `await` because it will deadlock your program:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks

Comment: @Dai, I added the ControllerActions to the question

Comment: What is `_fileService`?

Comment: I didn't want to pollute the question with that, the the _fileService 
 implementation and controller action Attributes are taken from the link I mentioned below the Controller action, which is: https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-upload-large-files/

Comment: You say your "question is very specific" but then you asked several questions.  Edit your post to include a *single* specific question.

Comment: Ok, I made the question shorter to include only the specific question