# How to Make a Synchronous service Call using HttpWebRequest (or) HttpClient in C#/XAML Metro App?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am Developing a C#/Xaml Metro Application  in that As per the Requirement I want to have a Synchronous service call , instead of ASynchronous Service Call.

This what I have used for Async Operation **but I want to make a Synchronus Service Call** :

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxxxxxx");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
     using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
    }
```

How can I make a Synchronous service Call using HttpWebRequest or HttpClient in C#/XAML Metro App ?

Comment: It was part of my requirment can let me know how can do it or let me know how can i wait until that asynchornous call is compleleted (apart from using await ) ?? i want to wait completely and dont do any operation until the asynchronous call is completed. ??

Comment: You should use async. It's a better model and means that your application is far less likely to feel "locked" to the user and non-responsive. Add a UI for "authentication" rather than do synch

Answer (score 2):

I use this method because it allows for doing other work before waiting:

```
        var t = request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        //do other work here
        t.Wait();
        using (Stream requestStream = t.Result)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the smaller change. Instead of `await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()`, use `request.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result`.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxxxxxx");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result)
{
}
```

More info : [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Answer (score 0):

> I am Developing a C#/Xaml Metro Application in that As per the Requirement I want to have a Synchronous service call , instead of ASynchronous Service Call.

The correct solution is to change the "requirement". Metro apps are supposed to be *asynchronous*, not *synchronous*. If you develop a Metro app with a synchronous UI (which is difficult but possible), it will likely be rejected from the app store.