# Will DataReader.LoadAsync() run in synchronously?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, async-await

I wrote a windows phone 8 app that using StreamSocket class, but found a strange situation. My code is as below

```
async void Connect() {

  await StreamSocketConnect();

  TryToSendAsync();

  ReceiveAsync();
}

async void ReceiveAsync() { 
                            //WriteLine("111");
   await DataReader.LoadAsync();
                            //WriteLine("222");
   DoReceiverCallBack();
}

async void TryToSendAsync(){

   await DataWriter.StoreAsync();

 }

void DoReceiveCallBack() { 
                             //WriteLine("333");
   ReceiveAsync();
                             //WriteLine("444");
}
```

In sequence, it should follow 333 => 111 => 444 => 222, but sometime I will get 333 => 111 => 222 => 444 while receiving data especially. Will it be synchronous sometimes??

Comment: Maybe this can help something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should really avoid using `async void` methods (except for event handlers).

Comment: Anything you can `await` can complete synchronously.

Comment: Thank you all, but how come about avoiding using `async void`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DataReader.LoadAsync` may complete synchronously.

Sockets have their own buffer; as data arrives on the socket, the OS will buffer it for you until you can read it. If there is enough data in the buffer for `LoadAsync` to complete, then it will be synchronous.