# Usage of EnsureSuccessStatusCode and handling of HttpRequestException it throws

Tags: .net, httprequest, system.net

What's the usage pattern of `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`? It disposes of the Content of the message and throws `HttpRequestException`, but I fail to see how to programmatically handle it any differently than a generic `Exception`. For example, it doesn't include the `HttpStatusCode`, which would have been handy.

Is there any way of getting more info out of it? Could anyone show relevant usage pattern of both `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` and HttpRequestException?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

The idiomatic usage of [`EnsureSuccessStatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode) is to concisely verify success of a request, when you don't want to handle failure cases in any specific way. This is especially useful when you want to quickly prototype a client.

When you decide you want to handle failure cases in a specific way, **do not** do the following.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(...);
try
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    // Handle success
}
catch (HttpRequestException)
{
    // Handle failure
}
```

This throws an exception just to immediately catch it, which doesn't make any sense.  The `IsSuccessStatusCode` property of `HttpResponseMessage` is there for this purpose. Do the following instead.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(...);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Handle success
}
else
{
    // Handle failure
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the real *integer* status code? when I try this I get a string such as "NotFound" instead of the 404 status code.

Comment: @NickG `(int)response.StatusCode` (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Note, the default HttpRequestException thrown by EnsureSuccessStatusCode() will have the reason phrase.  But you could access that property anyway in the response if it is not successful.

Comment: @TimothyShields I appreciate your color on allowing rapid prototyping. Why wouldn't you first read the `response.Content` value before jumping into the `// Handle success` and `// Handle failure` blocks?  In this way, you only read the `response.Content` property once. The only downside I can see to doing it this way is if the Content property is a long string, then you're basically slowing down the client, but if you're worried about speed, why not just use `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`?

Comment: I wrote my own version of EnsureSuccessStatusCode below.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476616/1040437  It delegates to the caller the responsibility get the `Content` prior to checking the status.

Answer (score 123):

I don't like EnsureSuccessStatusCode as it doesn't return anything meaninful.
That is why I've created my own extension:

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    public static async Task EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync(this HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return;
        }

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.Content != null)
            response.Content.Dispose();

        throw new SimpleHttpResponseException(response.StatusCode, content);
    }
}

public class SimpleHttpResponseException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }

    public SimpleHttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string content) : base(content)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

source code for Microsoft's EnsureSuccessStatusCode can be found [here](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/HttpClient/0.5.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0/Microsoft.Net.Http/Microsoft.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Net.Http)

Synchronous version based on [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously#11782373) :

```
public static void EnsureSuccessStatusCode(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return;
    }

    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (response.Content != null)
        response.Content.Dispose();

    throw new SimpleHttpResponseException(response.StatusCode, content);
}
```

What I don't like about IsSuccessStatusCode is that it is not "nicely" reusable. For example you can use library like [polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) to repeat a request in case of network issue. In that case you need your code to raise exception so that polly or some other library can handle it...

Comment: agree, the default code missing the feature to get a meaningful message from the return.

Comment: Your version works different than original implementation of `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`. You always dispose the `response.Content` (because finally is called always even after the `return;` statement) and it destroys the content for futher reading. Original implementation disposes the content only when status code does not indicate successful result.

Comment: you are right, since I posted I've updated my code locally

Comment: answered here on the same lines [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217619/how-do-i-get-statuscode-from-httprequestexception/33763053#33763053) 
As @Jookyn says just make sure there are no gap in custom and existing EnsureSuccessStatusCode

Comment: I don't get why you first `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and then check `if (response.Content != null)`

Comment: This approach is deal to putting the error handling right in an if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) because where I'm executing the HTTP request isn't necessarily where I know how I want to handle the error.

Comment: Polly now handles return results as well as exceptions, precisely to aid with this kind of scenario.  You can configure Polly to protect `HttpRequest` calls, and configure the policy both to handle certain exceptions, and certain `HttpResponseCode`s.  See the [example in the Polly readme here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#handing-return-values-and-policytresult)

Comment: How could `response.Content` be null when it has just had a method called on it?

Comment: @IanWarburton It does look really weird, but if I remember correctly there are some cases when this happens. Feel free to remove it and let me know if it does happen to be null...

Answer (score 8):

For .NET 5.0 or later, HttpRequestException returns HttpStatusCode property, and you should be using that instead.

Below is my proposed solution for pre-.NET 5.0. The only flaw is that since the ASP.NET Core framework resource manager is internal to the framework, I cannot directly re-use Microsoft's internationalized message strings, so I'm just using the verbatim English message literal here.

## Pros

- Logs the content for an 5xx server error

  - Sometimes, a server error is actually a client error in disguise, such as a client using a deprecated endpoint that finally got shut off.
- Makes it easier to uncover errors when writing integration tests using [`ConfigureTestContainer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.webhostbuilderextensions.configuretestcontainer?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

## Cons

- Inefficient.

  - If you read the response content, and the content is very long, you will slow the client down.  For some clients, with soft real-time response requirements, this jitter may be unacceptable.
- Incorrect responsibility for error logging and monitoring.

  - If this is a 5xx server error, why does the client care, since the client did nothing wrong?  Just call `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` and let the server deal with it.
  - Why not just check the server error logs when there is an Internal Server Error?
- Requires reading the `Content` property prior to checking the status.  There may be situations where this is not desirable, one of which is inefficiency.

## Usage

```cs
using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "controller/action"))
{
  using (var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage))
  {
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode2(content);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseClass>(content);
  }
}
```

## API

```cs
    public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
    {
        public static void EnsureSuccessStatusCode2(this HttpResponseMessage message, string content = null)
        {
            if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return;
            var contentMessage = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content) ? string.Empty : $"Content: {content}";
            throw new HttpRequestException(string.Format(
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Response status code does not indicate success: {0} ({1}).{2}",
                (int)message.StatusCode,
                message.ReasonPhrase,
                contentMessage)
                );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I use EnsureSuccessStatusCode when I don't want to handle the Exception on the same method.

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(User user)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        var userId = await GetUserIdAsync(user)
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public async Task GetUserIdAsync(User user)
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ...
        response = await client.PostAsync(_url, context);

        response.EnsureSuccesStatusCode();
        ...
    }
}
```

The Exception thrown on GetUserIdAsync will be handled on DoSomethingAsync.

Answer (score 2):

Since [Feb 24, 2020](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/3a95ea16bfd464dee520b09d9ffeaca62a62304d) the `HttpRequestException.StatusCode` property is set by `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`. If I understand correctly, the suggested extensions in this question are not needed anymore.