# C#: HttpClient with POST parameters

Tags: c#, post, parameters, httpclient

I use codes below to send POST request to a server:

```
string url = "http://myserver/method?param1=1&param2=2"    
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I don't have access to the server to debug but I want to know, is this request sent as POST or GET?

If it is GET, How can I change my code to send param1 & param2 as POST data (not in the URL)?

Comment: It is sent as post, `new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)`, by passing in `HttpMethod.Post` you are creating a POST request. What are param1 and param2?

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks. param1 & param2 are my parameters that I want to send them as POST parameters BUT query string.

Comment: @SandySands Thanks. It is in the Windows Phone Emulator and is hard to config it for Fiddler.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

A cleaner alternative would be to use a `Dictionary` to handle parameters. They are key-value pairs after all.

```
private static readonly HttpClient httpclient;

static MyClassName()
{
    // HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. 
    // Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. 
    // This will result in SocketException errors.
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.1
    httpclient = new HttpClient();    
} 

var url = "http://myserver/method";
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param1", "1" }, { "param2", "2" } };
var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent (parameters);

var response = await httpclient.PostAsync (url, encodedContent).ConfigureAwait (false);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    // Do something with response. Example get content:
    // var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().ConfigureAwait (false);
}
```

<del>Also dont forget to `Dispose()` httpclient, if you dont use the keyword `using`</del>

As stated in the Remarks section of the HttpClient class in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks), HttpClient should be instantiated once and re-used.

Edit:

You may want to look into [`response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097730/usage-of-ensuresuccessstatuscode-and-handling-of-httprequestexception-it-throws) instead of `if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)`.

You may want to keep your httpclient and dont `Dispose()` it. See: [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)

Edit:

Do not worry about using .ConfigureAwait(false) in .NET Core. For more details look at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html

Comment: That version does not work for me. The parameter received by the controller action is always null.

Comment: @d00d feel free to post a new question linked to this one explaining your problem.

Comment: and what about sending Get request by parameters?

Comment: @HoseinAqajani I think it would be a great question to ask in a new post. Feel free to link it here as comment.

Comment: `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`  is more concise as query parameter keys aren't necessarily unique.

Comment: While you are true (so here is an upvote), I dont like query parameter with duplicate. I dont only code in .net and since there is no spec about this, different server handle duplicate differently. Beside, duplicate can lead to [HPP](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/AppsecEU09_CarettoniDiPaola_v0.8.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it for DI:

```
using HttpClient httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("name set in builder host");
// httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Token {token}");
HttpResponseMessage? res = await httpClient!.PostAsync(url, content);
try
{
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return res;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Add error handling
}
```

content is:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data", "value")
};
FormUrlEncodedContent requestContent = new(values);
```

and clientFactory is the interface:

```
IHttpClientFactory
```

[msdn interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

Answer (score 0):

The answer as to whether the query is sent as a POST is, YES - the query is sent as a POST query.

If the server is an ASP.NET Web API and the query is not being seen by the server, then make sure that you decorate the parameter with [FromQuery] (sending it as a body should have either a [FromBody] of [FromForm])

Answer (score -8):

As Ben said, you are POSTing your request ( HttpMethod.Post specified in your code )

The querystring (get) parameters included in your url probably will not do anything.

Try this:

```
string url = "http://myserver/method";    
string content = "param1=1&param2=2";
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request,content);
```

HTH,

bovako

Comment: @JohnCroneh this isn't working anymore. Please accept the other answer below!

Comment: @JohnCroneh please change the accepted answer to one that works

Comment: @R.McManaman Actually it's a good answer if you would go with creating an no known method type. It's missing some "using" to make sure that it disposes and a "make sure it's converted", but it follows the PostAsync wrapper implementation.