# C# - Changing the name of attribute posted using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to post some data to a NodeJs based server.

```
Class Employee
{
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The functional code:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.Name = "TestUser";
var client = new HttpClient();

var task = client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlTemplate, e);
var result = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The node application expects a property by name `FirstName (instead of Name)`

In WCF, we can change the name of DataMember by placing an attribute on top of its definition:

```
[DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
public string Name  {   get;   set;  }
```

**Do we have similar option when sending data using HttpClient?**

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376133/c-httpclient-with-post-parameters

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use Newtonsoft.Json library. 
on you model class you can do

```
Class Employee
{
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FistName")]
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

before you PUT/POST, use JsonConvert.SerializeXXXX function to convert your object into string, and use the string content as your HttpClient payload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON serialization properties, as outlined in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm). Check out the related post: [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net).