# c# post request using httpparams and headers

Tags: c#, httpclient

I had a client app which was written in angular that post requests to `connect/token`

```
 const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', email)
      .set('password', password)
      .set('grant_type', "password")
      .set('scope', "offline_access");
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post<any>(this._baseAuthUrl + 'connect/token', body, { headers })
```

Now I have to write this in c#, but stuck with some part

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();  
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://mysite/connect/token");  
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

How do I add `HttpParams` and post request properly please?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376133/c-httpclient-with-post-parameters

Comment: thanks i'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                       {
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", email),
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "offline_access")
                        };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://mysite/connect/token");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    requestMessage.Content = content;
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

The above code is just an example to answer the question. But in your implementation, You should use HttpClient static and initialize it at once. [Read more](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)