# Add Params HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, api, post, dotnet-httpclient

I want to add a parameter, but I also have a body, I want to form this format:

```
HttpPost

http://localhost:8080/master/public/api/v1/invoice/send?token=123456
```

**Currently I have:**

```
HttpPost
http://localhost:8080/master/public/api/v1/invoice/send

 private readonly string UrlBase = "http://localhost:8080";
 private readonly string ServicePrefix = "master/public/api";



public async Task<DocumentResponse> SendInvoice<T>(Invoice body)
            {
            string controller = "/v1/invoice/send";
            try
            {

                var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

                var content = new StringContent(
                    request, Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json");
                var client = new HttpClient();



                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(UrlBase);
                var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", ServicePrefix, controller);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                Debug.WriteLine(response);
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return new DocumentResponse
                    {

                    };
                }
                var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentResponse>(result);
                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return new DocumentResponse
                {

                };
            }
        }
```

When I add it directly to the url, the request fails.

**Advance**

When I add it directly to the url, the request fails.
Inquiring about HttpClient, I found this, but how do I add it having a body?

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "token", "123456" } };
var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent (parameters);
```

Ref: [C#: HttpClient with POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376133/c-httpclient-with-post-parameters)

Thank you

Comment: That's definitely doable. You can search for **[FromBody]** and **[FromQuery]** for more details. FromBody maps with the body of your request and FromQuery maps with the query string parameters.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the author of the library, you can use RetroCoreFit, https://github.com/neurospeech/asp-net-core-extensions/blob/master/RetroFit/README.md which gives you better control over communicating for REST api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you format your URL you need to add the parameters like so:

```
var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", ServicePrefix, controller);

url = string.Format("{0}?token=123456", url);
```

Note the `?` between the URL and the query parameter.

You don't specify how you get the value for `token` into your method but, if it is a `readonly` value similar to `ServicePrefix` you can pass it as a parameter to `string.Format`:

```
var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", ServicePrefix, controller);

url = string.Format("{0}?token={1}", url, Token);
```

You can always put this on one line, but I have split it to make it easier to read :-)