# C# HttpClient: How to send query strings in POST Requests

Tags: c#, post, dotnet-httpclient

This is the POST Request, it works.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' 

'http://mywebsite.com/api/CompleteService?refId=12345&productPrice=600'
```

How to send this request using  `C#` => `HttpClient` => `client.PostAsync()` method?
Two methods have been tried but both failed.

**Method 1 (Failed, Response 404)**

```
string url = "http://mywebsite.com/api/CompleteService";
string refId = "12345";
string price= "600";
string param = $"refId ={refId}&productPrice={price}";
HttpContent content = new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

This would only work if API is to accept a request body, not query strings.

**Method 2 (Failed, Response  404)**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37443799/7768490

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "refId ", refId }, { "productPrice", price} };
var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, encodedContent)
```

Comment: maybe your end-point has a problem.

Comment: nope, it's tested working on Swagger, Postman, Axios.

Comment: Since 404, you have to post your controller and actions headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, None of the tried approaches put parameters in the `URL`!. You are posting on the below URL

```
"http://mywebsite.com/api/CompleteService"
```

However, something that works

```
string url = "http://mywebsite.com/api/CompleteService?";
string refId = "12345";
string price= "600";
string param = $"refId={refId}&productPrice={price}";
HttpContent content = new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Attach Parameters to URL and to get Response's Body, Use:

```
  try   
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url + param, content);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
```

Comment: You probably don't want the space in `refId =`

Comment: @RowanSmith I reused OP codes, and edition welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but nope this did not work. Same result. I cannot post my production API URL here, but I don't think this is a formatting issue.

Comment: Drop a Breakpoint in your debugger on the HttpResponseMessage line and check that the value of `content` is correctly formatted and what you expect.

Comment: @JayPow if you need to have URL parameters so you should attach, `URL + Param`

Comment: @AFarmanbar actually I think this is also wrong here: client.PostAsync(url + param, content), what's the purpose of doing param plus a content including param?thanks

Comment: @JayPow content is your request's body

Comment: @AFarmanbar but request body should be null in this case because my endpoint was but to only accept request parameters

Comment: @JayPow make it null. no problem

Comment: @AFarmanbar, actually I think it worked. ``URL+Param``, but I still need to add the empty HttpContent to ``client.PostAsync(url + para, content).Result.``

Comment: @AFarmanbar If you don't mind, can you also edit your answer and help me extract the response body out as well? it supposes to return a ``string`` response. Thanks!

Comment: @JayPow, it's recommended if your body is null, change the end-point to accept `GET` requests

Comment: @JayPow string or JSON? we have not string, it's plain text or json object

Comment: @AFarmanbar a string encoded to JSON.

Comment: @JayPow see update

Comment: I couldn't use ``await`` because my method is not ``async``, here is my code. And thanks to you @AFarmanbar  
 response = client.PostAsync(url + param, encodedContent).Result; string returnCnum = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: @JayPow, I'm not sure but try `client.PostAsync(url + param, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: @AFarmanbar it's already working. thank you. I used non-async methods.

Comment: @JayPow Depending on the context of your app, not awaiting your async call could cause [big problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context). If you're going to make async calls, make your method async. If you don't need asynchrony, make a synchronous call ([Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send?view=net-5.0)).