# Why use HttpClient over HttpWebRequest for synchronous requests

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpclient

In my scenario, I have to send data from one web application to a webapi which is an effective data store. The requests are necessarily synchronous and I most definitely want an `Exception` thrown if something goes awry as it means a critical part of the application is unavailable.

This is a derivative of, though not duplication of an existing question; [Why use HttpClient for Synchronous Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435520/why-use-httpclient-for-synchronous-connection).

Yet over and over, including in the article I see above, I see a consistent recommendation to use `HttpClient`, even in a synchronous scenario. The best reason I've seen is the accepted answer in the SO post above but it essentially boils down to;

> Use this because "shiny".

Which I'm not liking as an acceptable answer for my scenario. I'd prefer to use the correct object for the task at hand and this seems to be the older `HttpWebRequest`. Even Ben Watson's excellent resource "Writing High-Performance .NET Code" states the following;

> Another example is the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` class, which will
>   throw an exception if it receives a non-200 response from a server.
>   This bizarre behavior is thankfully corrected in the
>   `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class in .NET 4.5

But in my scenario, I actually *do* want that behavior. While there are a lot of good use cases for `HttpClient`, can anyone offer a good reason not to use `HttpWebRequest` in my scenario? Am I using the correct object or not? And more importantly, *why*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpClient` is designed to give more control over http protocol, where else doing same in `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` was not that straight forward. Apart from asynchronous, there are many benefits of `HttpClient`

**Benefits of `HttpClient`**

Biggest benefit of `HttpClient` is plugin architecture, that lets you change underlying behavior of HTTP protocol easily.

1. `HttpClient` is extensible, underlying `HttpMessageHandler` allows you to completely by pass underlying Microsoft's HttpClient implementation and you can plugin your own implementation. For example, in iOS and Android, instead of using .Net's HttpClient, we could use native Http stack.
2. It is easy to replace caching, cookies by customizing `HttpMessageHandler`
3. `CancellationToken` support is excellent when we want to cancel a long running Http request.
4. Not shiny, but important, Multi threaded, `HttpClient` is optimized to manage multiple requests with single instance. CPU time is utilized very efficiently without using too many locks (synchronous operations depend on locks, which is considerable overhead on CPU). Today we are living in world of micro services. In server with many clients to serve and mobile OS, CPU time is costly.

**Drawbacks**

Only drawback is `async/await`, you can't simply use async libraries easily in synchronous code without using a Task Runner or deadlocks. Though there are many libraries supporting how to synchronously use async code.

There is no great benefit of `HttpClient` on Desktop application with lots of CPU time as spare.

Comment: This link backs up the reasoning for not using async libraries in synchronous code.http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient`'s behavior is considered "cleaner" because a non-success response from the server doesn't necessarily mean something has gone awry. While it's not true of your situation, imagine a process that wants to check that a resource does *not* exist and expects that it typically does not. With `HttpWebRequest`, the normal execution flow throws an exception, which is kind of gross and can complicate things, whereas `HttpClient` does not.

For your specific scenario, the distinction is perhaps irrelevant. Other situations in your program might prefer the `HttpClient` behavior though, and it's nice to standardize on a single HTTP client instead of having to juggle two.

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient is not a replacement of WebClient/HttpWebRequest. HttpWebRequest gives you more flexibility, but at the same time it makes your code bit more verbose. Where as HttpClient provides a simple interface. You can use HttpWebRequest over HttpClient if you really want the additional features.

As per non-200 response code exceptions are concerned, HttpClient provides a way to simulate that behavior. You have to invoke

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

For more details please visit [Usage of EnsureSuccessStatusCode and handling of HttpRequestException it throws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097730/usage-of-ensuresuccessstatuscode-and-handling-of-httprequestexception-it-throws)