# Awaiting custom functions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to get my head around the new async features in C#, and so far the strangest thing I've noticed is that every example for async features has a function that awaits *another* async function defined in the framework, but none of them have custom code.

For example, what I want to is create an object from each line in a text file, but asynchronously, so that the UI thread doesn't freeze:

```
async Task Read()
{
    string[] subjectStrings = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    for (int i = 0; i < subjectStrings.Length; i++)
    {
        Task<Subject> function = new Task<Subject>(code => new Subject((string)code), subjectStrings[i]);
        try
        {
            Subject subject = await function;
            subjects.Add(subject);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            debugWriter.Write("Error in subject " + subjectStrings[i]);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I define a task that creates a new `Subject` object based on a line in the text file, and then await this task. If I do this, the debugger gets up to the `await` line, and then just stops. No more code is run, as far as I know.

If I was using the old async features, I'd just use Task.ContinueWith() and add a callback lambda that adds the subject to the list, and be on my way.

So my questions are:

1. Why does this code not work? How are you supposed to make a custom async method that doesn't use any async methods itself?
2. How are you supposed to *use* async methods? You can't use `await` unless you're in an async function, and you're not supposed to call an async method without await, so how do you first call that method from a synchronous method?

Comment: Example of [what you're talking about here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously) and why you shouldn't do that...

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: But this is only relevant to C#?

Comment: Say, what does your `Subject` constructor look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this code not work? How are you supposed to make a custom async method that doesn't use any async methods itself?

Use `await Task.Run` or `await Task.Factory.StartNew` to create and run the task. Calling `new Task` would create a task which isn't started yet. In most cases, this is unnecessary, but you can call `Start` on tasks created this way.

> How are you supposed to use async methods? You can't use await unless you're in an async function, and you're not supposed to call an async method without await, so how do you first call that method from a synchronous method?

Appropriate "root" async call depends on the type of application:

- In console application: `Wait` on returned `Task`.
- In GUI application: use `async void` event handler.
- In ASP.NET MVC: controllers can return `Task`.

Comment: Can you eleborate on how you'd do this in a console app? What do you mean by wait on a returned task?

Comment: `Main` method in Console app can't be asynchronous. So if you need to call `async Task f()` method, you call it `f().Wait()` instead of `await f()`. This blocks the calling thread until the call completes.

Answer (score 5):

You're not *starting* the task - so it will never finish.

Use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task` and it will create *and start* the task for you.

Note that you're still reading the file synchronously, which isn't ideal... and if your `Subject` constructor *really* takes that long to complete, I'd question whether it should be a constructor.

Comment: @Luaan the last point was that constructors shouldn't do expensive operations, not that they should do them asynchronously.

Comment: @StevenLiekens No misunderstanding there. That's the point I was trying to reinforce - if you need to run constructors parallely, you're doing something terribly wrong. A lot of things most likely.

Comment: It's not so much that each constructor takes a long time as there are several thousand of these constructors that I want to run without blocking the UI thread. I could use a separate .Read() function but surely that's less clear than a constructor?

Comment: @Miguel: It sounds like you should consider performing the *whole* "read file, call constructors" block within a single task. I'm assuming that `subjects.Add(subject)` affects the UI though? (If so, do that with all the subjects at the end.)

Comment: Yes I could (and probably should) do that. And yes, subjects is an ObservableCollection<Subject> that's bound to a WPF ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

> How are you supposed to make a custom async method that doesn't use any async methods itself?

You don't. If the method has no asynchronous work to do, it should be synchronous; it should not be `async`.

At the core, all `async` methods come down to one of two approaches. They either queue work to the thread pool via something like `Task.Run` (not recommended for library code), or they perform true asynchronous work via `TaskCompletionSource<T>` or a shortcut such as `Task.Factory.FromAsync`.

> How are you supposed to use async methods? You can't use await unless you're in an async function, and you're not supposed to call an async method without await, so how do you first call that method from a synchronous method?

You don't. Ideally, you should be `async` all the way. Console applications are an exception to this rule; they *have* to have a synchronous `Main`. But you should use async all the way for WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Windows Store, ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI, SignalR, iOS, Android, and Windows Phone applications, as well as unit tests.

You can use `async` methods via `await` and combinators such as `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WhenAny`. This is the most common way of using `async` methods, but not the only one; e.g., you can call an `async` method and consume it as an `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: "If the method has no asynchronous work to do, it should be synchronous"
I do have asynchronous work. I want to read this file into an array, *while* allowing the user to do whatever else they want in the UI. How should that be synchronous?

Comment: And if every method ever should be async, why isn't async functionality automatically implemented in WPF or Winforms?

Comment: @Miguel: If you're doing file I/O, then that's asynchronous, and you should make your method asynchronous. The point I was making is that *not* every method should be async; it should only be asynchronous if it has asynchronous work to do.

Comment: But it shouldn't matter if I'm doing I/O or not. Even if I was doing arbitrary math equations, *alongside* running the UI, shouldn't that be asynchronous?

Comment: @Miguel math equations are probably the best example of procedures that can benefit from multiple processor cores, depending on their complexity.

Comment: @Miguel: Math is an example of synchronous work. If you want to offload that from your UI, then you could use `Task.Run` to treat it as asynchronous. But you don't want to create a library that exposes an asynchronous API to do math, because that work isn't naturally asynchronous. [I explain why on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: I don't quite follow. Shouldn't *all* processing that's not UI related ideally be done on a separate thread? Why would you *ever* want to block the UI thread?

Comment: @Miguel one reason is because a free background thread might not always be immediately available. This still won't freeze your UI, but overall it will take your program longer to finish executing the code. /EDIT: actually that might be a misunderstanding on my part. *blush*

Comment: @Miguel: For example, if you're already on a background thread, then you don't want to call `Task.Run` to execute math code; you'd just want to execute it directly. As I explain in the blog post I linked to, this is much more of a problem on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing **waiting** and **working**. Waiting uses `async`/`await`, working does not. This still means you can `await` a CPU-bound task, but you have to run it manually, eg.:

```
var result = await Task.Run(YourLongOperation);
```

A distinction that helps me understand this on a gut level is, that **waiting** is cooperative - I voluntarily give up my share of CPU time, because I don't actually need it. **Working** on the other hand has to run parallel.

In a normal scenario, using only inherently asynchronous `async`/`await`s, there doesn't have to be more than the single thread you started with. It is usually a bad idea to combine CPU-bound operations with I/O-bound ones (CPU-bound will block, unless you explicitly run the task parallely).

Answer (score 0):

I won't bore you with Yet Another Technical Explanation™, instead let me show you a practical example based on your code sample.

Starting with a synchronous version that does all the work on the calling thread.

```
class SubjectFactory
{
    public IEnumerable<Subject> Read(string filePath)
    {
        string[] subjectStrings = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        return Parse(subjectStrings);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Subject> Parse(IEnumerable<string> subjects)
    {
        string code = "XYZ";

        foreach ( var subject in subjects )
        {
            yield return new Subject(code, subject);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that the constructor in `Subject` is lightweight, the biggest bottleneck is `File.ReadAllLines`. Why? Because disk I/O is inherently slow.

So how do you go about wrapping that in a task?

If the framework had a `File.ReadAllLinesAsync()` method, you could await that and be done with it.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Subject>> ReadAsync(string filePath)
{ // Doesn't exist!
    string[] subjectStrings = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath);

    return this.Parse(subjectStrings);
}
```

Unfortunately, life is difficult, and so is parallel programming. It's looking like you'll have to reinvent the wheel.

```
private async Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string filePath)
{
    ArrayList allLines = new ArrayList();

    using ( var streamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)) )
    {
        string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();

        allLines.Add(line);
    }

    return (string[]) allLines.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

Now you can do the same thing as before, but use your custom method `ReadAllLinesAsync()`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Subject>> ReadAsync(string filePath)
{
    // call with 'this' instead of 'File'
    string[] subjectStrings = await this.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath);

    return Parse(subjectStrings);
}
```

With all that in place, in your WPF app all you got to do is this:

```
var filePath             = @"X:\subjects\";
var subjectFactory       = new SubjectFactory();
var subjectsCollection   = await subjectFactory.ReadAsync(filePath);
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Subject>(subjectsCollection);
```