# Invoking an async method synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I need to call synchronously an asynchronous method for reasons out of my control. I'm developing a library, that uses another library that works asynchronously and I need use it from an implementation of the `Stream` class. Such class contains synchronous and asynchronous methods, and I am feeling uneasy about the synchronous ones:

```
public override sealed int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{ 
    // potential deadlock on single threaded synchronization context
    return ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).Result;
}

public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   return await _lib.ReadAsync(buffer,offset,count);
}
```

I have been reading [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097066/307976),  and in the comments @Stephen Cleary states that the solution is not good, since some ASP.NET parts expect a `AspNetSynchronizationContext`. I am developing a library, so I do not know where my classes are going to be called from.

What would be the safest way of invoking an async method synchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stephen Toub covers all the various approaches with their corresponding drawbacks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) on his blog.

There are only two general-purpose solutions, neither of which is ideal:

1. Duplicate the logic in your layer; have your synchronous methods call the synchronous methods in the library. (This assumes that the library *has* synchronous methods as well as asynchronous).
2. Block on the returned task, similar to your example code. This assumes that the library always uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`, an assumption that is out of your control. If the library is context-free, then it may be safer to throw the asynchronous invocation into a `Task.Run` and block on that task instead. Also, ensure you unwrap exceptions when blocking on a task, since `Wait` or `Result` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

Both of these solutions have somewhat serious maintenance problems.

Comment: Am I missing something? `Task<T>.Wait` will block regardless of the continuation policies.

Comment: @Gusdor: Blocking like that is [an easy way to cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

Comment: Touché! I was missing something. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It seems that the first one is the only reasonable and safe solution. The `Task.Run` approach would be a good temporary solution till I schedule some time to write the synchronous methods.

Comment: @vtortola: I do normally recommend the first one, but neither one is ideal.