# Async Foolproof Validation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-validators, foolproof-validation

When using `MVC Foolproof Validation`, is it possible to have a custom validation `asynchronous`? I am wanting to retrieve an object from a `DbSet` in a custom validation, to check if the object exists.

Is this possible? If not, is there a work around that achieves the same result?

Here is my code:

```
public class RequiredThumbnailAssetId : ModelAwareValidationAttribute
{
    static RequiredThumbnailAssetId() { Register.Attribute(typeof(RequiredThumbnailAssetId)); }
    public async override Task<bool> IsValid(object value, object container)
    {
        var model = (IGridViewItemWithAssetId)container;
        if (model.thumbnailAssetId <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        CanFindLocationDatabaseContext db = new CanFindLocationDatabaseContext();
        Asset asset = await db.assets.FindAsync(model.thumbnailAssetId);
        if (asset == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> 'CanFindLocation.CustomValidations.RequiredThumbnailAssetId.IsValid(object,
>   object)': return type must be 'bool' to match overridden member
>   'Foolproof.ModelAwareValidationAttribute.IsValid(object, object)'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the classes defined in the post [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously) and then separate the override you need and the async call out into separate methods. This would allow you to call the synchronous override from the async request.

```
public class RequiredThumbnailAssetId : ModelAwareValidationAttribute
{
    static RequiredThumbnailAssetId() { Register.Attribute(typeof(RequiredThumbnailAssetId)); }

    public async override Task<bool> CheckValid(object value, object container)
    {
        var valid = AsyncHelpers.RunSync<bool>(() => isValid(value,container));
        return valid;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value, object container)
    {
        var model = (IGridViewItemWithAssetId)container;
        if (model.thumbnailAssetId <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        CanFindLocationDatabaseContext db = new CanFindLocationDatabaseContext();

        Asset asset = await db.assets.FindAsync(model.thumbnailAssetId);

        if (asset == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```