# Implementing asynchronously methods synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have an abstract class `FilesManager` which manages some files.

The methods are marked as `Task<>` because i might be saving / reading the files to a cloud server via `http request`, so i want to mark them as `asynchronous`.

However, for now, i save the files on local disk, `synchronusly`.

Is ok to return empty `Task` in order to fix the error?

For example:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return; });
```

The below implementation of `LocalDiskFilesManager` throws exception, because each method is expected to return a `Task<>` object.

```
public abstract class FilesManager
{
    public abstract Task SaveFileAsync(XDocument xDocument);
    public abstract Task<XDocument> GetFileAsync(Guid file_Id);
}

// Synchronously
public class LocalDiskFilesManager : FilesManager
{
    public override Task SaveFileAsync(XDocument xDocument)
    {
        string path = GetFilePath();
        xDocument.Save(path);

        // is ok to return an empty task? does it affects the performance / threads?
        // return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return; });
    }

    public override Task<XDocument> GetFileAsync(Guid file_Id)
    {
        string path = GetFilePath(file_Id);
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);

        return xDocument;

        // is ok to return an empty task? does it affects the performance / threads?
        // return Task<XDocument>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return xDocument; });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782373/706456)

Comment: I think that answer explains how to run an asynchronous task synchronously, but i need to know how to "fake" a synchronous task to look asynchronous :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better would be to use [`Task.FromResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for now.

> Creates a `Task<TResult>` that's completed successfully with the specified result.

E.g.

```
public override Task<XDocument> GetFileAsync(Guid file_Id)
{
    string path = GetFilePath(file_Id);
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);

    return Task.FromResult(xDocument);
}
```

Which avoids actually scheduling a separate task so should address your threading concerns.

And for the non-generic `Task`, I'd usually just do:

```
private static Task _alreadyDone = Task.FromResult(false);

public override Task SaveFileAsync(XDocument xDocument)
{
    string path = GetFilePath();
    xDocument.Save(path);

    return _alreadyDone;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. is there any specific reason you marked the `_alreadyDone` as static?

Comment: @RaraituL - It's a premature optimization - you could just have the method `return Task.FromResult(false);` but since there's nothing interesting in that task we may as well create one, once, and always return it. Saving an allocation.