# Why does "RunAsync().Wait()" never finishes running, but if i take off the ".Wait()" it returns me the right result?

Tags: c#, wpf, api

I have the following code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri("https://api.trakt.tv/");
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("trakt-api-version", "2");

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("trakt-api-key", "");

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("search?query=Arrow&type=Show"))
            {
                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run it, it get stuck at the part:

```
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("search?query=Arrow&type=Show"))
```

This never finishes running. But if I take off the `.Wait()` from     `RunAsync().Wait();` then the code run to the end normally. Why is it getting stuck when I put `.Wait()` on the method call?

I have to put it, because if i don't the rest of the code will continue to run and wont wait the method to complete...

Comment: look at the comments on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously/11782373#11782373

Comment: I have a blog post on [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) that you may find useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a deadlock here.

Code after **await** will be executed in the same thread as it started. This is the way await works. But since you've already blocked the thread by calling **Wait()**, it goes to be locked forever

Comment: So does it means that even if  i don't put Wait() after RunAsync() the code will wait the method end before it continues?

Comment: Nope. In your case it just finishes MainWindow constructor. And when httpClient.GetAsync() method is executed, you'll get code in RunAsync() continued.

Comment: but how can i make MainWindow constructor just continue when RunAsync() finishes?

Comment: I think you shouldnt go with smth async when you need sync behavior. You could either use WebClient that provides sync methods or rewrite your RunAsync() in syncronous manner. E.g. instead of await httpClient.GetAsync("search?query=Arrow&type=Show") you'll use httpClient.GetAsync("search?query=Arrow&type=Show").Result etc.

Comment: @GabrielDuarte: You should move that out of the constructor, into and `await`able `async` method.