# MongoDB InsertMany vs BulkWrite

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB for keeping log data. And my goal is zero dropped log record. Now I am using `InsertManyAsync` for writing multiple log data. But in MongoDB there is also method like `BulkWriteAsync`.

What is the difference in performance between `InsertMany` and `BulkWrite`? In local writing and writing over network?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Ok that's two questions:

**InsertMany vs BulkWrite**

Using `BulkWrite` you can do many operations in a single connection to mongoDB. *Internally*, `InsertMany` uses `BulkWrite`, so there's no difference, it's just for convenience.

[This question was already solved.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921533/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-2-0-insertmanyasync-vs-bulkwriteasync)

**Sync vs Async**

When you perform a sync operation, your aplication will wait for MongoDB to finalize the work. With a async operation you can perform many operations at the same time. Server, and client side.

[This was already solved too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30216264/2010764)

Answer (score 2):

BulkWrite supports a mix of writing operations (inserts, delete and update), while insertMany, as indicated by its name, only inserts documents.

Comment: This should be the top answer in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

BulkWriteAsync under the cover uses InsertManyAsync for insert operations.  The only difference is BulkWriteAsync allows you to perform different operations (insert, update, delete) under one roof. However if you are debating between BulkWriteAsync and InsertManyAsync for inserting bunch of documents, it's recommended to use InsertManyAsync directly.

Comment: _BulkWriteAsync under the cover uses InsertManyAsync_ FYI it's actually the other way around, InsertMany uses BulkWrite