# Sync method calling async method that returns Stream causes stream to be closed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a sync method that calls an async method that returns a Stream.

The async method makes a call to web api and returns a stream that represents a document.

Whenever I call the async method from within my sync method, the stream is returned as closed.

If I call the async method from within another async method, the stream is returned opened.

I can't call the async method from within another async method because I have to implement an interface from an external library and the code that calls the async method is done from within a sync method that's defined in the interface.

So - SyncMethod -> AsyncMethod -> WebApi returns a closed stream

AsyncMethod1 -> AsyncMethod -> WebApi returns an open stream.

Here is the signature for my async method -

```
public async Task<Response<Stream>> GetSomeDocument()
```

In my sync method, I call the async method like so -

```
var task = this.someClass.GetSomeDocument();

task.Wait();
```

This is where it blows up and throws ObjectDisposedException -

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

task.Result.CopyTo(memoryStream);
```

Any idea why this works if I call my async method from within an async method using await, but calling it from a sync method doesn't?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance you can show us the -> *Async Method* -> that you want to wrap in Sync call? The problem you're facing is not from your side.. It depends on the implementation of *AsyncMethod*.

Comment: Btw - this solution using the AsyncHelpers class worked but I was wondering if there is a newer solution that involves less code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously?rq=1

Comment: Post all code that operates on the stream in question

Comment: @Chris there could be an option if you are allowed to change the code of *AsyncMethod*. The reason that Asynchelper if working is because it's using a new SynchronizationContext over Current one. Same can be achieved by using **ConfigureAwait(false)** in *AsyncMethod* where it is creating the Task.

Comment: This is a console application, right?

Comment: Are you calling `Dispose` on any stream or using the `using`  statement? It would be better if you posted a small and complete code sample that we could test.