# HttpClient PostAsync does not respond in case of windows phone but works fine in android and ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
HttpResponseMessage myResponse = myClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent).Result;
```

i am passing `uri` in `theUri` and `json` data in `theContent`

this works fine in android and ios but it does not respond in windows phone is anything wrong in this statement

Comment: can you try sending your data wrapped inside a `StringContent` object?

Comment: in windows phone it does not even sends a request to server

Comment: well, you need to identify `why`?

Comment: i am not sure but is there any changes in settings in order to send request to server for app which are not downloaded from windows phone store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Result means that your method will block. But it isn't recommended because it will cause a deadlock. You need to be careful when you use Result property or Wait().

When you use async method I recommend you que you declare async method and you call the function with await.

```
public async Task Method()
{
    HttpResponseMessage myResponse = await myClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);
}
```

If you can't declare the method as async and you need to use a async method. I recommend you that use this class for convert async method in sync method:
[How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously/5097066#5097066)

Comment: now i am using async await now it does goes into deadlock but problem is i am not able get result inside myResponse
I think still request is not sent from app to service (i am not sure)

Comment: I recommend you that you use the helper class of the link and you put a breakpoint in the catch, because there are times that the error is hidden.

Comment: somewhere i read use await TaskScheduler.Default.SwitchTo(); // When blocking on Result from UI thread.
but i am getting error at "await TaskScheduler.Default.SwitchTo();"
Error : 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler' does not contain a definition for 'SwitchTo' and no extension method 'SwitchTo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)