# How can avoid set my method as async when I'm using ReadAsStringAsync()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task

I'm developing a library with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I have this method to PUT something on a ASP.NET Web Api 2 web service.

```
public async Task<string> PrepareAndStartv2(
    string orderNumber,
    string userName,
    string systemName)
{
    string uri =
        string.Format(PrepareAndStartUri, orderNumber, userName, systemName);

    string batchName = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webApiHost);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PutAsync(uri, content);
        HttpResponseMessage message = response.Result;

        Task<string> task = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        batchName = await task;
    }

    return batchName;
}
```

I added `message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to get a string returned by the method. And after that I've been forced to and `Task<string>`, `await` and `async` everywhere.

Is there another option to read a string in a `HttpContent` without using `await`, `Task<string>` and `async`?

Maybe running a Task inside this `PrepareAndStartv2` method that wait will I'm reading the string with `ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Comment: Of course, it is a duplicate question. I will add my solution as an answer to share knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) after calling an async method to avoid your own method to be forced async:

```
public string PrepareAndStartv2(
    string orderNumber,
    string userName,
    string systemName)
{
    string uri =
        string.Format(PrepareAndStartUri, orderNumber, userName, systemName);

    string batchName = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webApiHost);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage message = client.PutAsync(uri, content).Result;
        batchName = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    return batchName;
}
```

Comment: Stephen Cleary: _"[.Result can easily cause **deadlock** in async code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)"_