# Is there a way to synchronously run a C# task and get the result in one line of code?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, synchronous

I have an async method which works when I call it as follows:

```
var result = await someClass.myAsyncMethod(someParameter);
```

Is it possible to do something like this, but in one line of code?

```
var task = someClass.myAsyncMethod(someParameter);
task.RunSynchronously();
var result = task.Result;
```

Comment: ``someClass.myAsyncMethod(someParameter).Result;``

Comment: What is the point of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can do it using the `Result` property directly after the calling of method:

```
var result = someClass.myAsyncMethod(someParameter).Result;
```

and a more better way is to wrap it in `Task.Run()` to avoid deadlocks like:

```
var result = Task.Run(() => {

   return someClass.myAsyncMethod(someParameter);

}).Result;
```

I also found this [RunSynchronously() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321435(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN, but that won't server your question as you want a on liner simple code.

Comment: That will await the task to run to completion?

Comment: it will block the caller thread until the task completes returning result

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: can you please show what the syntax is for `Task.Run()`?

Comment: Even using `Task.Run()` can cause deadlocks in some situations that I don't have exact examples for right now. You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously/5097066#5097066 for a more in-depth workaround

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ Thank you for the solution, I did not know `Result` would block.

Comment: @Alexandru but ideally you should be calling async method asyncronously

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ It depends on the situation ;)

Comment: @Alexandru It's virtually always wrong.  The exceptions would be quite rare.

Comment: I am not sure about "Result" will be return if Task is non generic.


 public class Task<TResult> : Task

 which have Result property.
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
public TResult Result
{
get { return IsWaitNotificationEnabledOrNotRanToCompletion ?
GetResultCore(waitCompletionNotification: true) : m_result; }
}

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself doing this often you can write a small extension

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static T SyncResult<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        task.RunSynchronously();
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var result = Task.SyncResult();
```