# Proper way to await something in a method that does not return void, Task, or Task<T>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Say I am implementing an interface with the method signature

```
String FooBar();
```

And later on I am implementing this interface in my class

```
public String FooBar()
{
    return "";
}
```

But at some point I would like to `await` something

```
public async Task<String> FooBar()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    return "";
}
```

**How can I `await` something in this scenario without having to alter the method signature to**

```
Task<String> FooBar();
```

Is the proper way to do this with `Task.WaitAll`? Or is there a more accepted pattern?

**EDIT:** I do not feel that my question is an exact duplicate, though very much related, to [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously) . I am more worried about how to implement the interface than I am about how to call the `async` function. But I do admit the bolded question does equate to the duplicate question.

I do see now it is more appropriate to return `Task` because of the possibility of implementors of the interface calling `async` methods. Otherwise I "lock them out" of doing so properly.

Comment: `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is generally nicer than Wait or WaitAll since it will throw the actual exception wtihout the AggregateException wrapper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I await something in this scenario without having to alter the method signature

The *proper* solution is to alter the method signature. Any interface method that *could* be implemented asynchronously should return `Task`/`Task<T>`.

(From a design perspective, this is very similar to deciding whether an interface should derive from `IDisposable` - the interface has to predict its own implementation details).

As far as *improper* solutions go, this is just another variant of the "call async method from sync method" question. There is no ideal, universal, or commonly-accepted solution. There are only a few hacks you can do, each with different drawbacks. I cover these in my [async brownfield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

I write all my code where I can take advantage of `async` calls (and when it makes sense to do so) using `async` code. If there is code that needs to call the same method but synchronously then I prefer to write extension methods for my (interface) types where I need to expose a synchronous version of an `async` method. This allows me to not have to rewrite the business logic but instead it just calls through the existing implementation. It also means I have to write 1 less unit test later against the business logic. The only reason you might not want to do this in all scenarios is if there is a large loop that is performance critical, in that case the extra overhead of the `async` wrapper could be a problem and you should then invest in re-writing a 2nd version of that method.

```
// note that I added cancellation support, this is personal preference

public interface IFoo
{
    Task<String> FooBarAsync(CancellationToken token);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public async Task<String> FooBarAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500, token);
        return "";
    }
}

public static class FooSyncExtender
{
    public static String FooBar(this IFoo foo)
    {
        // this is one way to call async from sync code
        return foo.FooBarAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you leave method signature unchanged, it means method will no longer take benefits of async/await, which is use limited number of threads to do lots of async operations using auto-generated state machine by compiler.
Once you use something like .Wait / .WaitAll / .GetResult inside your method it means you block current thread until async operation finishes.

Normally you want to have all your application async/await compatible all way down to get real benefits from it.

I would make interface with 2 methods: synchronous version and async version. Internally synchronous version may call async version and just wait for its execution.