# Run method that returns IAsyncOperation<TResult> synchronously

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to run a method that returns IAsyncOperation synchronously. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to convert `IAsyncOperation` to `Task`. Call `AsTask()` extension for that case. Then just `Wait()` its end and fetch the results. In that case your code should look like:

```
//Your async operation
public IAsyncOperation<object> Operation()
{
    //Doing some important stuff
}

public void Initialize()
{
    Task op = Operation().AsTask();
    op.Wait();
    object results = op.Result;    //Here's our result
}
```