# C#: how to use Async task in sync environment?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm facing a problem as below:

- I need to implement a traditional interface which will be called in a sync environment:

  ```
  public interface IWorker {
      int GetResult();
  }
  ```
- I need to use a third party lib which uses `async/await`

  ```
  Task<int> ThirdPartyClass.WorkAsync();
  ```

How can I use the `async` method

```
    public class MyWorker : IWorker {
          public int GetResult()
          {
               // ??? how to use the async calls ???
               new ThirdPartyClass().WorkAsync();
          }
    }
```

I know there is a `Result` property, like `int result = c.WorkAsync().Result;`, but as far as I know it blocks the current thread and may cause dead locks. For example, calling an `async` method and use `Result` in a Winforms button event handler can cause dead lock problem.

Is there a better way to use `async/await` for such situation?

Comment: nope. you'll have to block, or make `GetResult` async.

Comment: It's always better to keep the async workflow async. You can go with a blocking Wait() on the task but that might end up in a deadlock. 

I'd rather suggest to have a async method like 'Task<int> GetResultAsync()'.

Or Callbacks are your best bet but in both cases, you'd end up modifying the IWorker. Better to add one than modify the existing one which is possibly used in a lot of places.

Comment: There's several ways to do it, but if your method expects an `int` returned, then you *have* to wait for the task to finish.

Comment: @DanielA.White so all functions calling `GetResult` directly or indirectly must be async?

Comment: Most of the answers on the linked duplicate are horribly bad. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5110698/263693) is the only good one.