# Async and await to synchronous method using Task

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, uwp, task

I am very new with this async/await concept, so I apologise for asking anything that is obvious.

I need to send email and the new API require me to use **async** and await. Problem is that a lot of my methods need to call this "send email" **synchronously**.

So, I create a synchronous wrapper method:

```
private Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string content)
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
}

private void SendEmail(string email, string content)
{
    Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await SendEmailAsync(email, content));
    try { tsk.Wait(); }
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    {
        throw aex.Flatten();
    }
}
```

But for some reason, **tsk.Wait()** does not waiting for **await SendEmailAsync(...)** to finish. So, I need to add `ManualResetEvent`. Something like this

```
private void SendEmail(string email, string content)
{
    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        mre.Reset();
        try { await SendEmailAsync(email, content); }
        finally { mre.Set(); }
    });

    mre.WaitOne();
    try { tsk.Wait(); }
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    {
        throw aex.Flatten();
    }
}
```

But any exception thrown by **SendEmailAsync(...)** will NOT be captured by **tsk.Wait()**. My question is:

1. Why **tsk.Wait()** does NOT wait for **await SendEmailAsync(...)**
2. How to catch exception thrown by **await SendEmailAsync(...)**

Thanks!

Comment: Just call `SendEmailAsync(email, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: For running async code in a sync manner, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097066/5062791

Comment: You shouldn't do "sync over async" as it tends to cause deadlocks! Stephen Cleary will be here soon to point that out ;-), but if you really have to I can recommend the AsyncPump from Stephen Toub (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/). But that should not be used "inside" your libary.

Comment: For reference to Stephen Cleary's blog regarding this, http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html): "... since StartNew does not understand async delegates, what that task actually represents is just the beginning of that delegate ..."

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use `Task.Result` and `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but it resulted in deadlock. I have tried solution posted by ColinM in stackoverflow link and it worked. @ColinM please posted your answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run asynchronous code in a synchronous manner by using the following extensions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097066/5062791

```
public static class AsyncHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute's an async Task<T> method which has a void return value synchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task<T> method to execute</param>
    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> task)
    {
        var oldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        var synch = new ExclusiveSynchronizationContext();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synch);
        synch.Post(async _ =>
        {
            try
            {
                await task();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                synch.InnerException = e;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                synch.EndMessageLoop();
            }
        }, null);
        synch.BeginMessageLoop();

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute's an async Task<T> method which has a T return type synchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Return Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="task">Task<T> method to execute</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T RunSync<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
    {
        var oldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        var synch = new ExclusiveSynchronizationContext();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synch);
        T ret = default(T);
        synch.Post(async _ =>
        {
            try
            {
                ret = await task();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                synch.InnerException = e;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                synch.EndMessageLoop();
            }
        }, null);
        synch.BeginMessageLoop();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldContext);
        return ret;
    }

    private class ExclusiveSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
    {
        private bool done;
        public Exception InnerException { get; set; }
        readonly AutoResetEvent workItemsWaiting = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        readonly Queue<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>> items =
            new Queue<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>>();

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("We cannot send to our same thread");
        }

        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            lock (items)
            {
                items.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(d, state));
            }
            workItemsWaiting.Set();
        }

        public void EndMessageLoop()
        {
            Post(_ => done = true, null);
        }

        public void BeginMessageLoop()
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object> task = null;
                lock (items)
                {
                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        task = items.Dequeue();
                    }
                }
                if (task != null)
                {
                    task.Item1(task.Item2);
                    if (InnerException != null) // the method threw an exeption
                    {
                        throw new AggregateException("AsyncHelpers.Run method threw an exception.", InnerException);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    workItemsWaiting.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        }

        public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I should start by stating that you should follow @ChrFin's comment and try to refactor your code to make it asynchronous, instead of trying to run an existing async library synchronously (You'll even note an improvement in the application's performance).

---

To accomplish what you seek, you should use `SendEmailAsync(email, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

*Why not `SendEmailAsync(email, content).Wait()`?* you may ask.

Well, there's a subtle difference. `Wait()` will wrap any runtime exception inside an `AggregateException` which will make your life harder if you attempt to catch the original one.

`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will simply throw the original exception.

You code would look like this:

```
private void SendEmail(string email, string content)
{
    try
    {
        SendEmailAsync(email, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // ex is the original exception
        // Handle ex or rethrow or don't even catch
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matias, I should have mentioned that I've tried to use both `Task.Result` and `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but both methods caused deadlock in my case (MVC .NET) which forced me to try to use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` which is also wrong. But I have used the solution posted by ColinM and it worked fine. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to send email and the new API require me to use async and await. Problem is that a lot of my methods need to call this "send email" synchronously.

The *best* solution is to remove the "synchronous caller" requirement. Instead, you should allow `async` and `await` to grow naturally through your codebase.

> for some reason, tsk.Wait() does not waiting for await SendEmailAsync(...) to finish.

That's because you're using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, which is a [dangerous API](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

> I have tried to use Task.Result and Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() but it resulted in deadlock.

I explain this deadlock in detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

> I have used the solution posted by ColinM and it worked fine.

That's a dangerous solution. I don't recommend its use unless you understand ***exactly*** how it works.

If you *absolutely must* implement the antipattern of invoking asynchronous code synchronously, then you'll need to use a hack to do so. I cover the various hacks in an article on [brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). In your case, you could probably just use the thread pool hack, which is just one line of code:

```
private void SendEmail(string email, string content) =>
    Task.Run(() => SendEmailAsync(email, content)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

However, as I stated at the beginning of this answer, the *ideal* solution is to just allow `async` to grow. Hacks like this limit the scalability of your web server.