# Converting async Task Response to String

Tags: c#, async-await

First of all, I would like to say, I'm quite new to C#.

I'm trying to create a POST request which sends some data to a PHP file somewhere on a different server.

Now, after the request is send I would like to see the response, as I'm sending back a JSON string from the server as a success message.

When I use the following code:

```
public MainPage()
{

     this.InitializeComponent();
     Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);

     responseBlockTxt.Text = start();
}

public string start()
{
    var response = sendRequest();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);

    return "";
}

public async Task<string> sendRequest()
{
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
               { "vote", "true" },
               { "slug", "the-slug" }
          };

          var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

          var response = await client.PostAsync("URL/api.php", content);

          var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

          return responseString;
      }

}
```

The output is:

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

So, how would I see all the results from this?

Comment: Use .Result to get result of task

Comment: @MaksimSimkin results in the following error: `An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: @Chris Don't mix async and blocking calls (`.Result, .Wait()`) you may get deadlocks. Go async all the way. Read up here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @Chris how is the start method being called?

Comment: @Nkosi like this for now: `responseBlockTxt.Text = start();`

Comment: Is that line of code being done in an event handler? If yes there is a really easy fix.

Comment: @Nkosi I updated the post with some more code

Comment: @Chris this is a classic XY problem. in future when explaining a problem provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue so that those trying to help you have the complete picture and would be able to provide better answers. It reduces the back and forth trying to figure out what is really the problem when the information provided is vague.

Comment: What is the nameplace for "Windows.UI" on WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go Async all the way. Avoid blocking calls when calling async methods. `async void` is allowed in event handlers so update page to perform the call on load event

Read up on [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

And then update your code accordingly

```
public MainPage() {    
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;     
}

public async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    responseBlockTxt.Text = await start();
}

public async Task<string> start() {
    var response = await sendRequest();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);

    return response;
}

private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<string> sendRequest() {
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "vote", "true" },
        { "slug", "the-slug" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    using(var response = await client.PostAsync("URL/api.php", content)) {
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, we're going in the right direction. The only error that pops-up now is at `this.Loaded += OnLoad;`. Error: `No overload for 'OnLoad' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'`

Comment: @Chris, that was a typo on my part. Change `EventArg` to `RoutedEventArgs`. Will update answer to fix typo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `start` method, the `SendRequest` method returns a `Task<string>` and that's what you get on your `response` variable. Since you are attempting to run an `async` method synchronously you have to do some extra stuff, try this:

```
public string start()
{
    var response = sendRequest().ConfigureAwait(true)
                                .GetAwaiter()
                                .GetResult();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);

    return "";
}
```

That get the actual result inside your awaitable `Task<string>`. If you want to find some more info on this take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Comment: Hey @Luiso. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the following error pops-up now: `An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: That means there is something wrong with your request, you had an issue with concurrency now you have one with the request, please update your question and add as much data as you can so we can improve on that

Comment: What I'm showing is pretty much all I have. The url I'm using is working just fine. I'm used to use it in AJAX. Now trying to use the same thing in here.

Comment: I think you should take a look at what the actual `Exception` looks like. With what you're giving us we can only tell there is something wrong with the request, and not _what_ went wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

I Guess

```
public string start()
{
    var response = sendRequest();
    Task<String> t = sendRequest();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t.Result);

    return "";
}

public async Task<string> sendRequest()
{
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
               { "vote", "true" },
               { "slug", "the-slug" }
          };

          var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

          var response = await client.PostAsync("URL/api.php", content);

          var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

          return responseString;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string start()
  {
    var response = sendRequest().ConfigureAwait(true)
                                .GetAwaiter()
                                .GetResult();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
    return "";
   }
```

I have Tried this. It is working perfectly.