# Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay in a synchronous method with both a sync and async caller

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, thread-sleep

I have a synchronous method:

```
public void DoStuff() {  
    DoThings(); 
    GraphClient.SetExtendedProperty(user, propertyName, value);     // this method occasionally throws an exception
    DoOtherThings();
}
```

`Call3rdPartyMethod` makes a REST API call using the [Azure Ad Graph Client API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) which throws an exception if I try to set the value of an extended property on Active Directory and it isn't found.  This usually happens a new user is added to the directory and the Extension Properties feature hasn't extended the user schema before I want to set the values (it seems to take a few seconds).

I replaced the SetExtendedProperty call with my own wrapper containing the call in a busy-wait loop thus:

```
public void TrySetProperty(GraphObject user, string propertyName, string value)
{

   var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

   for (int retry = 0; retry < 5; retry++)
   {
      try
      { 
          if (retry > 0)
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
              GraphClient.SetExtendedProperty(user, propertyName, value);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      { 
          exceptions.Add(ex);
      }
   }

   throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
  }
}
```

The issue is that I want to be able to call `TrySetProperty` from both a synchronous and asynchronous method:

```
public void DoStuff() {  
    DoThings(); 
    TrySetProperty(user, propertyName, value);
    DoOtherThings();
}

public Task DoOtherStuffAsync() {
    await DoAsyncThings();
    TrySetProperty(user, propertyName, value);
    await DoOtherAsyncThings();
}
```

I can't change SetExtendedProperty to be asynchronous, and I'm concerned I shouldn't be using Thread.Sleep if i'm calling it from an asynchronous method - rather Task.Delay().  Can anyone advise?

Comment: Don't ever mix blocking code with async await. It's deadlock waiting to happen. I'd suggest writing all your methods in the async style with no blocking code, then using [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097066/14357) to afford yourself a synchronous call to an asynchronous method.

Comment: @Botonomous the `retry` is there to avoid a delay at the first try, but insert a delay before each following try.

Comment: deleted my answer, because @spender is right, it's not a good suggestion to mix async and sync methods this way.

Comment: I've had to use the `AsyncHelpers` (in the answer pointed to in my previous comment) once in production and, although it worked, TBH it didn't sit nicely. Do you **really** need to go synchronous?

Comment: I may have just found my solution to this.  There is an ExecuteSingleAsync().Result example on GetObjectById here: https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-6-schema-extensions/.  I guess I can now write two version of TrySetProperty - one with Thread.Sleep and one with Task.Delay?

Comment: You also could try to `await Task.Run(() => TrySetProperty(…)` in case of the async version, as you don't really do anything async in your property setter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

- Making a fully-asynchronous version if possible. REST APIs are naturally asynchronous, but some client libraries are still outdated (i.e., have only synchronous methods).
- Expose only an asynchronous version if possible (since the operation is naturally asynchronous). If you *must* support synchronous APIs (e.g., for backwards compatibility), then use the [boolean argument hack in my article on brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).
- Use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) for retry logic.

Assuming that you've got a fully-asynchronous version of `GraphClient.SetExtendedProperty` working, then your code could look like this:

```
private static readonly Policy syncPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
private static readonly Policy asyncPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

private static async Task TrySetProperty(GraphObject user, string propertyName, string value, bool sync)
{
    if (sync)
        syncPolicy.Execute(() => GraphClient.SetExtendedProperty(user, propertyName, value));
    else
        await asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => GraphClient.SetExtendedPropertyAsync(user, propertyName, value));
}

public static Task TrySetPropertyAsync(GraphObject user, string propertyName, string value) =>
    TrySetProperty(user, propertyName, value, sync: false);
public static void TrySetProperty(GraphObject user, string propertyName, string value) =>
    TrySetProperty(user, propertyName, value, sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If your `TrySetProperty` logic really is that simple (i.e., it literally only calls a single method on `GraphClient`), then you can do away with the boolean argument hack for simpler code:

```
private static readonly Policy syncPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
private static readonly Policy asyncPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

public static async Task TrySetPropertyAsync(GraphObject user, string propertyName, string value)
{
  await asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => GraphClient.SetExtendedPropertyAsync(user, propertyName, value));
}

public static void TrySetProperty(GraphObject user, string propertyName, string value)
{
  syncPolicy.Execute(() => GraphClient.SetExtendedProperty(user, propertyName, value));
}
```