# Run async Task sychronously w/exception propagation

Tags: c#, async-await

What is the preferred way to run an async method synchronously?

This is what I currently do:

```
void RunSync() {
    var task = Task.Run(() => RunAsync());
    task.Wait();
}

async Task RunAsync() {
     throw Exception("test");
}
```

My problem with the above code is that `task.Wait()` throws an `AggregateException` rather than the actual exception thrown by `RunAsync` which is what I'd prefer.

Is there a way to propagate the actual exception from `RunAsync` without resorting to catching `AggregateException` and unwrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast answer:

Change this:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => RunAsync());
task.Wait();
```

to this:

```
var task = RunAsync();
task.Wait();
```

You should not wrap async methods with Task.Run for running it.
Read SO answers 'How to call async methods from sync context', e.g. [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Comment: from your link- is all that dispatcher / message pumping stuff related to running in a windows / forms application?  if i am running a console application should i be fine?

Comment: There are some nuances in different environments (WinForms, Console App, IIS), but for your case it's not so important.

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend to read articles by Stephen Cleary about asyncs (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html). There is all you need to know about async keyword :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to unwrap the `AggregateException`, do this:

```
RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```