# Xamarin Android HttpClient PostAsync

Tags: c#, post, xamarin.android, httpclient

I have an android app in Xamarin native. I am trying to consume a Restful service from an API in another server.

I have this:

```
private async Task<string> CreateCellphone(string url, Cellphone cell)
        {
            string cellphone = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cell);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(cellphone, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                string responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseMessage;
            }
        }
```

I execute this on a button call like this:

```
private void RegisterButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create new GUID
            Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();

            // Store the created GUID in a private shared preferences file
            var localGUID = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("LocalSetup", FileCreationMode.Private);
            var guidEdit = localGUID.Edit();
            guidEdit.PutString("GUID", obj.ToString());
            guidEdit.PutBoolean("IsRegistered", true);
            guidEdit.Commit();

            // Create the cellphone record into the database for DB admin to activate
            _url = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.cellphone_api_url);
            Cellphone cell = new Cellphone();
            cell.CellphoneId = obj.ToString();
            var response = CreateCellphone(_url, cell);                
        }
```

But when my code gets to the postAsync method, nothing happens, it just continues without actually sending the code to the endpoint, I have no idea what I might be doing wrong, because all documentation I have on PostAsync tells me this is how to send json data for a Restful Web api endpoint.

Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the call to `CreateCellphone` or  nothing will happen because the `response` Task will get disposed of almost immediately. Not sure if you can make your button click method `async` in Xamarin, but I would try this:

```
private async void RegisterButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      //^^^^^
      //Add this
{
    //snip

    await CreateCellphone(_url, cell);
}
```

Failing that, there are various way to call an async method synchronously, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously).

Comment: I used to async methods, now I just execute the async on the actual request and it works like a charm, thank you!