# How to convert Task<object> to object in an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asmx

I have some legacy code that uses `asmx` web methods. I have no control over the decision to use any other technology but I need to modify it a little.

The method currently returns a custom object, but I need to modify it to call an awaited method, so the method should now become `async` and the return value is now forced to become `Task<Object>`

Is there a way to return `Object` instead of `Task<Object>` ? Here's a sample of my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public async Task<Foo> DoSomethingAwaited()
        {

           return await WaitForMe();

        }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously?rq=1

Comment: take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types