# Deadlock while logging http requests into main UI C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

In my WinForms app I want to see raw request/response data when it interacts with webApi. I need to show request/response in UI RichTextBoxes. To do this I set up my HttpClient as follows:

```
        private HttpClient client;
        private void CreateService()
        {
            client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), this))
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(this._URI)
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
```

My Logging Handler:

```
    public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private SimplySignRestClientAsync _client;

        public LoggingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, SimplySignRestClientAsync client) : base(innerHandler)
        {
            this._client = client;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string p_Request = "";
            if (_client._updateRequest != null)
            {
                p_Request = request.ToString();
                if (request.Content != null)
                {
                    p_Request += "\n\nContent:\n" + FormatJsonString(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());    
                }

                //_client._request.Text = p_Request; << this works but causes a cross-thread exception in debug only
                SetText(p_Request); << This deadlocks the UI
            }

            return response;
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (_client._request.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                _client._response.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                _client._request.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
```

If i try to access richtextbox directly it works  only when i execute app without debugging. But during debug it comes up with cross-thread exception.

This is how I call httpClient:

```
//This is how the original call gets initiated from UI
private void uiLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Agent resp = Client.Login(new Credentials(uiUsername.Text, uiPassword.Text));
   uiAuthToken.Text = Client.getAuthToken();
}

//this method has to stay synchronous, but it in turn calls an async method below
public Agent Login(Credentials loginInfo)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await LoginAsync(loginInfo));
    return task.Result.Content;  <<< this is where the application stops if i hit pause during debug when deadlock happens
}

//
async public Task<RestResponse<Agent>> LoginAsync(Credentials loginInfo)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(this._URI + "api/users/login", loginInfo);

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    RestResponse<Agent> respAgent respAgent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestResponse<Agent>>(content);

    return respAgent;
}
```

as I understand my "return task.Result.Content" blocks the UI thread and "_client._response.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });" is waiting for that to unblock causing deadlock. But I'm not sure how to make invoke wait too.

Comment: Check this on how to run async code synchronously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using proper asynchronous constructs, you need to make the entry point (your `Click` event handler) asynchronous, and never block on asynchronous code as it causes the deadlock you are facing.

```
//This is how the original call gets initiated from UI
private async void uiLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Agent resp = await Client.Login(new Credentials(uiUsername.Text, uiPassword.Text));
   uiAuthToken.Text = Client.getAuthToken();
}

public async Task<Agent> Login(Credentials loginInfo)
{
    var result = await LoginAsync(loginInfo);
    return result.Content;
}
```

Comment: Login(Credentials loginInfo) function has to stay synchronous

Comment: @AnKing Why? There's no way you can make this correctly with a synchronous method

Comment: because i'm using req/resp outputs in a testApp. The main app is using all synchronous calls. I wanted to imitate synchronous calls in a test app too

Comment: @AnKing You are presumably connecting to an online service to handle the login, yes? That means you have exactly two options. A] You handle the login asynchronously, or B] you block the UI thread (a.k.a. freeze the entire app) while you wait for the online service to respond.