# Why in one case GetAwaiter() block my application and in another application is not blocked?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have 2 projects, both use Net 5, entity framework Net 5 and async. The unique difference is that the project that is blocked use Sql Server and the other use Sqlite. But I guess the database is not the reason.

Porject 1, that is blocked:

```
public void Main()
{
    SqlServerEFNet5 miRepository = new SqlServerEFNet5();
    miRepository.GetAllMyRowsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}


public Task<List<MyType> GetAllMyRowsAsync()
{
    using (ContextEfNet5 dbContext = new ContextEfNet5(_optionsDbContext))
    {
        return await dbContext.MyEntities.FromSqlRaw("Select * from MyType").ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

My project 2, it is not blocked:

```
private void Main()
{
    MyViewModelProperty.AddRange(Service.Service.GetAllMyRowsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()));
}


public static async Task<List<MyType>> GetAllMyRowsAsync()
{
    using (Context myDbContext = new Context())
    {
        return await myDbContext.MyType.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Really in my second project I don't use raw sql query, but I have tried use only pure linq in my first project and still is blocked.

Also, in my first project I don't populate a collection of the view model, that it could be affect because it is used by the view, but in my second project I populate a collection of the view model, so it is not the problem.

I don't understand why in one case it is blocked and in another case isn't.

Edit 01:

If I use this code in the project 1, it is not blocked:

```
        Task<int> miTask = Task<int>.Run(() => { return 0; });

        int myIntResult = miTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Edit 02: the suggestion solution of another question doesn't help me because it suggest to use await, but I can't use it because I have to call this async code in the constrcutor, and a constructor can't be async.

Edit 03: I have found in this [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously) a helper that it works.

Comment: One projects runs in an environment with a `SynchronizationContext`, and the other one [without](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)?

Comment: Why don't you just use `async Task Main()` and get rid of the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: I will check about environment with a SynchronizationContext. But in neither both projects I set this. About why don't use async task it is because I am using this code in the constructor of the class, and in another methdos that are event handler and can't be async.

Comment: @GSerg in the link you give me, he tells I can use GetAwaiter() .GetResult() with no worry about deadlocks, but it is what I am doing in both cases.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't help in my case. In both projects, I use the GetAwaiter() in the constructor of the main class, and in the first case is blocked and in the second is not.

Comment: My assumption is that it might have to do with one project not having `ConfigureAwait(false)` all the way. Could you in the first project test if it works if you add this at the start of the `GetAllMyRowsAsync` method: `await Task.Delay(50).ConfigureAwait(false);`? (Please don't use that as a solution if it works, it's just a test to confirm the problem). Important that it's done at the start, before the other `async` call!

Comment: Which one uses sqlLite and which one Sql Server? It actually metters cause EF Providers for them are different
.ConfigureAwait(false) NOT ALWAYS helps, if  somewhere down the line EF/Micrsoft uses old event-based async pattern and converts it to TPL - .ConfigureAwait(false) will not work, Cause event-based pattern will always capture context.
Read this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development Section The Blocking Hack. And a reason for asking which one - i want to find source code of provider to prove the point

Comment: @NikitaChayka The first project, that is blocked, use Sql Server, the second project that works use Sqlite.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured out. The deadlock is becuase of `SynchronizationContext` and it's capturing as stated many times in comments to your question.
Usually solution is either use `await` all the way up, or `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which you doing. BUT!

As stated here (section **The Blocking Hack**):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development

If somewhere down the line Microsoft/EF uses conversion from old event-based async pattern then `ConfigureAwait(false)` will have no effect, cause context will be already captured anyway.

And turns out they do such conversion, here is the source of `SqlCommand` for SqlServer:

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/bd89b6433892214eed41e97afb0a9430d11d4681/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netfx/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs

Look there for line **2996**.

Now why SqlLite is working fine - because SqlLite doesn't not support async I/O, so all asyncs for SqlLite are fake, you could clearly see it in source of `SqliteCommand`:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteCommand.cs

Line **406**.

And explanation for "fake" is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/async